# Fastest way to convert a dict's keys & values from `unicode` to `str`?

Tags: python, casting, types

I'm receiving a dict from one "layer" of code upon which some calculations/modifications are performed before passing it onto another "layer". The original dict's keys & "string" values are `unicode`, but the layer they're being passed onto only accepts `str`.

This is going to be called often, so I'd like to know what would be the fastest way to convert something like:

```
{ u'spam': u'eggs', u'foo': True, u'bar': { u'baz': 97 } }
```

...to:

```
{ 'spam': 'eggs', 'foo': True, 'bar': { 'baz': 97 } }
```

...bearing in mind the non-"string" values need to stay as their original type.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

```
DATA = { u'spam': u'eggs', u'foo': frozenset([u'Gah!']), u'bar': { u'baz': 97 },
         u'list': [u'list', (True, u'Maybe'), set([u'and', u'a', u'set', 1])]}

def convert(data):
    if isinstance(data, basestring):
        return str(data)
    elif isinstance(data, collections.Mapping):
        return dict(map(convert, data.iteritems()))
    elif isinstance(data, collections.Iterable):
        return type(data)(map(convert, data))
    else:
        return data

print DATA
print convert(DATA)
# Prints:
# {u'list': [u'list', (True, u'Maybe'), set([u'and', u'a', u'set', 1])], u'foo': frozenset([u'Gah!']), u'bar': {u'baz': 97}, u'spam': u'eggs'}
# {'bar': {'baz': 97}, 'foo': frozenset(['Gah!']), 'list': ['list', (True, 'Maybe'), set(['and', 'a', 'set', 1])], 'spam': 'eggs'}
```

Assumptions:

- You've imported the collections module and can make use of the abstract base classes it provides
- You're happy to convert using the default encoding (use `data.encode('utf-8')` rather than `str(data)` if you need an explicit encoding).

If you need to support other container types, hopefully it's obvious how to follow the pattern and add cases for them.

Comment: And what would one do if some values are lists/sets/etc?

Comment: @Philip: Add cases for them. Answer updated, and then updated again for nesting containers within containers.

Comment: you forgot tuple and frozenset, Richi

Comment: @SilentGhost: Lucky for you I'm so anally retentive I can't just leave it alone.  8-) Answer updated.

Comment: Maybe he omitted them :) But yeah tuples are pretty common.

Comment: I tried use this decision and get a exception `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. My dict was simplest: {'Login': 'zxczxc',
 'Name': '\xd0\x98\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8f',
 'Surname': '\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xb7\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5'}

Comment: I fixed it. For non unicode string should use `if isinstance(data, basestring):` instead `if isinstance(data, unicode):`

Comment: Why do you use `type(data)(map(convert, data))` instead `map(convert, data)`?

Comment: @AbbasovAlexander: So that you get back the same type you put in - a tuple becomes a tuple, a list becomes a list, a set becomes a set, and so on.

Comment: Do I need to be afraid of hitting python's maximum recursion depth?

Comment: @Moberg: Only if your data structure is nested many hundreds of levels deep.

Comment: in Python3, `if isinstance(data, basestring):` to `if isinstance(data, str):`

Comment: I got no `convert` module in Python 3 :-(

Answer (score 25):

I know I'm late on this one:

```
def convert_keys_to_string(dictionary):
    """Recursively converts dictionary keys to strings."""
    if not isinstance(dictionary, dict):
        return dictionary
    return dict((str(k), convert_keys_to_string(v)) 
        for k, v in dictionary.items())
```

Comment: Yup, this seems like the correct way of doing it, the inline and other versions really aren't enough for real world scenarios.  Too bad there is no reliable inline recursionless way to accomplish this.  Or maybe there is based on python str(...) json conventions?

Comment: This is my favorite, to only convert the keys, which is what I was looking for. Small typo: you need an additional () around the dict() argument that is returned.

Comment: The only problem with this solution is if your keys are NOT all strings (i.e. int type)

Comment: @MrWonderful and why is that? I can't see any problem in calling ``str`` on an int

Comment: @Germano : Of course you can call str() on an int, but you get a str.... not an int anymore.  So the type of the key would be changed from an int to a str, which is *more* than changing unicode to str -- the original question.

Comment: @MrWonderful I agree about the original question. The conversion to a string of an int is perfectly consistent with the name of the method though ;)

Comment: This only does keys.

Comment: This fails to handle other nested iterable types.

Answer (score 12):

If you wanted to do this inline and didn't need recursive descent, this might work:

```
DATA = { u'spam': u'eggs', u'foo': True, u'bar': { u'baz': 97 } }
print DATA
# "{ u'spam': u'eggs', u'foo': True, u'bar': { u'baz': 97 } }"

STRING_DATA = dict([(str(k), v) for k, v in data.items()])
print STRING_DATA
# "{ 'spam': 'eggs', 'foo': True, 'bar': { u'baz': 97 } }"
```

Comment: For 2.7 and onwards this can be simplified as follows: `{ str(key):value for key,value in data.items() }`

Answer (score 4):

for a non-nested dict (since the title does not mention that case, it might be interesting for other people)

```
{str(k): str(v) for k, v in my_dict.items()}
```

Comment: {str(k): str(v) for k, v in my_dict.items()}

Comment: This helped convert my keys to strings which i needed to compare against my dataframe column

Answer (score 3):

```
def to_str(key, value):
    if isinstance(key, unicode):
        key = str(key)
    if isinstance(value, unicode):
        value = str(value)
    return key, value
```

pass key and value to it, and add recursion to your code to account for inner dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

To make it all inline (non-recursive):

```
{str(k):(str(v) if isinstance(v, unicode) else v) for k,v in my_dict.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> d = {u"a": u"b", u"c": u"d"}
>>> d
{u'a': u'b', u'c': u'd'}
>>> import json
>>> import yaml
>>> d = {u"a": u"b", u"c": u"d"}
>>> yaml.safe_load(json.dumps(d))
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `print(*(dict.keys()))`

The * can be used for unpacking containers e.g. lists. For more info on * check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/400753/8782672).

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.