# How to get values from this dictionary string from Django?

Tags: javascript, django

My request.POST is like this:

```
QueryDict: <QueryDict: {u'rows[]': [u'4f58707ba5e97c09d5000003', u'4f5881a3a5e97c0ba8000000']}>
```

I am trying to get those values into an array. But my code

```
request.POST['rows[]']
```

results only '4f5881a3a5e97c0ba8000000' Why? How can I take both of the values into an array?

Comment: Looks like a stringified Python dictionary? Do you need to handle it in JavaScript?

Comment: can you provide a little more context to your question? do you need to pass the dictionary to the javascript or what?

Comment: Dictionaries are not strings, they're Python, not Django, and what you're asking is easily answered with even the most minimal of effort at your search engine of choice. But, here I'll even save you that effort: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: If everything is solved by the search engine, why stackoverflow stands?

Comment: @ChrisPratt might want to check the accepted answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QueryDict` is not a standard Python dictionary. It's a subclass of `MultiValueDict`: https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3.1/django/utils/datastructures.py#L223 You can get both items by using `request.POST.getlist('rows[]')`.

Answer (score 1):

Below is how I would do it.

```
my_dict = {u'en': u'description', u'tr': u'aciklama'}

print my_dict[u'en']
print my_dict[u'tr']
```

Something that seems wierd to me is that your dictionary keys are unicode strings. If you want to normalize them check out this answer: [Fastest way to convert a dict's keys & values from `unicode` to `str`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254454/fastest-way-to-convert-a-dicts-keys-values-from-unicode-to-str)

Answer (score 0):

From javascript:

```
var str = obj.en
```

From python:

```
str = obj['en']
```

or in python if you want to get 'en' or a default value in case it doesn't exist:

```
str = obj.get('en', 'Default Value')
```