# Type error when changing directory

Tags: python

I keep getting the following error when tring to change directory..can anyone help what is wrong and how to overcome this?

CODE SNIPPET:-

```
print "changing dir..."
print "BUILDDIR: " + BuildDir
os.chdir(BuildDir)
print "Done changing dir..."
```

ERROR:-

```
changing dir...
BUILDDIR: /local/mnt/workspace/username/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_CHO_3.5.04.03.00.003.047_msm8216/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 682, in <module>
    flist = fd.readlines()
  File "Main.py", line 654, in main
    picked_gerrits = []
  File "Main.py", line 126, in RepoSync

TypeError: must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591575/python-typeerror-must-be-encoded-string-without-null-bytes-not-str

Comment: @spaz - i looked at it..am using front slashes "/" as you see from the error shot..

Answer (score 0):

hard to tell without being able to reproduce. try:

```
'/'.join(map(str.strip, BuildDir.split('/')))
```

if not this is what [google brought me](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2010/12/24/common-mistakes-as-web-developer/):

```
import os, re

_split = re.compile(r'[\0%s]' % re.escape(''.join(
    [os.path.sep, os.path.altsep or ''])))

def secure_filename(path):
    return _split.sub('', path)

print '/%s/' % '/'.join([secure_filename(x) for x in BuildDir.split('/') if x])
```

Comment: not clear on what you are suggesting....what needs to be done do the BuildDir variable before doing os.chdir(BuildDir)

Comment: last try, pls give it a go