# How to convert unicode to integer or float in dictionary in Python

Tags: python, unicode, integer

For example, I have a dictionary, which is like:

```
Degree = {'Union': u'1', 'Cook': u'3', 'Champaign': u'7'}
```

How can I convert it as:

```
Degree = {'Union': 1, 'Cook': 3, 'Champaign': 7}
```

I know it's not a hard question, but I try many methods, like json, *.items... but I just do not get it.

Comment: Have you tried `int`?! Why don't you show what you've tried and describe what the problem is?

Comment: yes, but I thought int can only covert it one by one...

Comment: Yes, so add a loop. This isn't a code-writing service, read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: Yes, I know. Sorry about that. I also read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254454/fastest-way-to-convert-a-dicts-keys-values-from-unicode-to-str 
I tried... and still don't get it...

Comment: Ok, so... where did you get to? *Where is **your** code?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dictionary comprehension:

```
converted_degrees = {key: int(value) for (key,value) in Degree.items()}
>>> converted_degrees
{'Union': 1, 'Cook': 3, 'Champagne': 7}
```

Comment: Thank you so so so much!!! It works now. I used to use for and if to distinguish the string and int then I failed many times. Again, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Use int(value) to convert it :

```
values = {k:int(v) for(k,v) in Degree.items()}
```