# Only select dictionary keys that are tuples?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary with both string and 2-tuple keys. I want to convert all the 2-tuple keys from (x,y) to strings that are x:y. Here is my data:

```
In [4]:

data = {('category1', 'category2'): {'numeric_float1': {('Green', 'Car'): 0.51376354561039017,('Red', 'Plane'): 0.42304110216698415,('Yellow', 'Boat'): 0.56792298947973241}}}
data
Out[4]:
{('category1',
  'category2'): {'numeric_float1': {('Green', 'Car'): 0.5137635456103902,
   ('Red', 'Plane'): 0.42304110216698415,
   ('Yellow', 'Boat'): 0.5679229894797324}}}
```

However, this is the dictionary output I want:

```
{'category1:category2': 
    {'numeric_float1': 
        {'Green:Car': 0.5137635456103902,
         'Red:Plane': 0.42304110216698415,
         'Yellow:Boat': 0.5679229894797324}}}
```

I have altered code from [a previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254454/fastest-way-to-convert-a-dicts-keys-values-from-unicode-to-str) to create a recursive function that changes all the keys.

```
In [5]:

def convert_keys_to_string(dictionary):
    if not isinstance(dictionary, dict):
        return dictionary
    return dict((':'.join(k), convert_keys_to_string(v)) for k, v in dictionary.items())

convert_keys_to_string(data)
```

However I cannot get the function to avoid non-tuple keys. Because it does not avoid non-tuple keys, the function fixes the 2-tuple keys but messes up the non-tuple keys:

```
Out[5]:
{'category1:category2': {'n:u:m:e:r:i:c:_:f:l:o:a:t:1': {'Green:Car': 0.5137635456103902,
   'Red:Plane': 0.42304110216698415,
   'Yellow:Boat': 0.5679229894797324}}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `':'.join(k)` to `k if hasattr(k, 'isalpha') else ':'.join(k)`. This will use the unaltered object if it has the attribute `isalpha`, which means it's probably a string, or join the object with a colon otherwise. Alternatively (thanks, @Padraic), you can use `':'.join(k) if isinstance(k, tuple) else k`.

Comment: I wanted to feed the duck types, though.

Comment: I don't follow, what will `if hasattr(k, 'isalpha')` do that `issinstance(k, str)` won't?

Comment: Instead of asking whether it's a duck, I'm listening for the quack. :)

Comment: isinstance will make any str quack ;)

Comment: I'd say you're not really listening for the quack, you're looking whether it can quack. But you inspired my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You only care about dicts and tuples so just check for both recursing on the values:

```
def rec(d):
    for k,v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            rec(v)
        if isinstance(k, tuple):
            del d[k]
            d[":".join(k)] = v

rec(data)

from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(data)
```

Output:

```
{'category1:category2': {'numeric_float1': {'Green:Car': 0.5137635456103902,
                                            'Red:Plane': 0.42304110216698415,
                                            'Yellow:Boat': 0.5679229894797324}}}
```

This modifies the original dict which I presumed was the actual goal.

If you wanted it to work for all iterables except a str:

```
from collections import Iterable
def rec(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            rec(v)
        if isinstance(k, Iterable) and not isinstance(k,  str):
            del d[k]
            d[":".join(k)] = v
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [@TigerhawkT3's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30632680/1672429), here's somewhat of a "quack-listener":

```
[':'.join(k), k][k in k]
```

You can use that instead of your unconditional `':'.join(k)`. Other ideas:

```
[':'.join(k), k][''.join(k) == k]
[':'.join(k), k][str(k) == k]
```

I should say that these are confusing and do unnecessary work, though. This is just for fun/golfing. The `... if isinstance(...) else ...` is the proper way. Although, `k in k` might actually be faster than `isinstance(k, str)`:

```
>>> timeit('k in k',             "k = 'numeric_float1'")
0.222242249806186
>>> timeit('isinstance(k, str)', "k = 'numeric_float1'")
0.3160444680784167

>>> timeit('k in k',             "k = ('Yellow', 'Boat')")
0.21133306092963267
>>> timeit('isinstance(k, str)', "k = ('Yellow', 'Boat')")
0.5903861610393051
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It works, I do warn about its badness, and I think it's educational/interesting.