# JSON output in Bottle, Python and MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bottle

I am running Bottle and python to pull my data from MongoDB. my output comes in JSON object format.
I used to have the following

```
{u'product': u'mortgage', u'Total_Product': 146533}
{u'product': u'debt collection', u'Total_Product': 65639}
```

but wanted to get rid of the 'u and get the following format:

```
'product':'mortgage', Total_Product: 146533
'product':'debt collection' 'Total_Product:65639
```

After running this code, I am left with a blank screen with no results and no error message. Any suggestion?

```
# find a single  with all aggregates 
choices = dict(
    aggr1 = db.complaints.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":"$disputed", "Total_Disputed":{"$sum":1}}},{"$sort":{"Total_Disputed":-1}},{"$project":{"_id":0, "disputed":"$_id", "Total_Disputed":1}}]),
    aggr2 = db.complaints.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":"$product", "Total_Product":{"$sum":1}}},{"$sort":{"Total_Product":-1}},{"$project":{"_id":0, "product":"$_id", "Total_Product":1}}]),
    aggr3 = db.complaints.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":"$response", "Total_Response":{"$sum":1}}},{"$sort":{"Total_Response":-1}},{"$project":{"_id":0, "response":"$_id", "Total_Response":1}}]),
    aggr4 = db.complaints.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":"$submitted", "Total_Submitted":{"$sum":1}}},{"$sort":{"Total_Submitted":-1}},{"$project":{"_id":0, "submitted":"$_id", "Total_Submitted":1}}]),
    aggr5 = db.complaints.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":"$timely", "Total_Timely":{"$sum":1}}},{"$sort":{"Total_Timely":-1}},{"$project":{"_id":0, "Timely":"$_id", "Total_Timely":1}}])
)

def convert_keys_to_string(choices):
    """Recursively converts dictionary keys to strings."""
    if not isinstance(choices, dict):
        return choices
    return dict((str(k), convert_keys_to_string(v)) 
        for k, v in dictionary.items())
aggr1 = 'aggr1'
aggr2 = 'aggr2'
aggr3 = 'aggr3'
aggr4 = 'aggr4'
aggr5 = 'aggr5' 

    return bottle.template('analytics.tpl',  things1 = choices[aggr1], things2 = choices[aggr2], things3 = choices[aggr3], things4 = choices[aggr4], things5 = choices[aggr5])

bottle.debug(True)
bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8082)
```

the tpl is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> @2015 </title>
</head>
<body>
<p>

</p>
<p>
<ul>
%for thing1 in things1:
<li>{{thing1}}</li>
%end
</ul></p>
<p>
<ul>
%for thing2 in things2:
<li>{{thing2}}</li>
%end
</ul></p>



</body>
</html>
```

kindest regards

Comment: Are you asking to get rid of the u's?  If so its just denoting it as a unicode string.

Comment: Yes I am trying to get rid of the u's @riotburn

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254454/fastest-way-to-convert-a-dicts-keys-values-from-unicode-to-str

Comment: ok I am having a look at it @riotburn

Comment: what is analytics.tpl?

Comment: just updated with tpl. @Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You are using the convertion to a string of a dict in your template `{{thing1}}`.

Just write your template, to format the dict-entries as you want:

```
%for thing1 in things1:
<li>'product':'{thing1.product}', Total_Product: {{thing1.Total_Product}}</li>
%end
```

or

```
%for thing1 in things1:
<li>'product':'{thing1.product}' 'Total_Product:{{thing1.Total_Product}}</li>
%end
```

your question is not clear, which one you prefer.