# Json array adds an u character python

Tags: python, arrays, json, amazon-s3

I'm loading an array from a bucket content in S3, but when I load the array  and printed the string using the following code:

```
for obj_array in bucket_array.objects.all():
  json_array = obj_array.get()['Body'].read()
```

it has the `u` character at the beginning of each value like follows:

## current array:

```
{
  u'values': [{
    u'sensor': u'2',
    u'temperature': u'24.5',
    u'unit': u 'celsius',
    u'datetime': u'23-02-2017 21:03:50'
  }, {
    u'sensor': u'2',
    u'temperature': u'24.5',
    u'unit': u'celsius',
    u'datetime': u'24-02-2017 4:00:36'
  }]
}
```

So, when I tried to do `array_data = json.loads(json_array)` it throws me the following error:

```
Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1): ValueError
Any ideas how to solve this?
```

Comment: Can you use `ctrl - k` to format your code properly? It is hard to read what your code is doing right now.

Comment: use json.dumps(json_array) to convert your son to python dict!

Comment: The 'u' character only means that it is a unicode formatted.

Comment: You are having a Python (2) dictionary already, not JSON. the `u` marks a Python 2 unicode string. BTW single quotation marks are also disallowed in JSON.

Comment: I don't think you need the `json.loads()`, it appears you already have a python data structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to convert a dict's keys & values from \`unicode\` to \`str\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254454/fastest-way-to-convert-a-dicts-keys-values-from-unicode-to-str)