# How to remove "u" in output. Error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, json

I am trying to store JSON output in a variable. Initially I got the output but it was prepended with character "u" (unicode). Below is the initial output:

```
{u'imdata': [{u'nvoNws': {u'attributes': {u'dn': u'sys/epId-1/nws', u'status': u'', u'persistentOnReload': u'true', u'monPolDn': u'', u'modTs': u'2017-02-24T00:50:47.373+00:00', u'uid': u'0', u'childAction': u''}}}, {u'nvoPeers': {u'attributes': {u'dn': u'sys/epId-1/peers', u'status': u'', u'persistentOnReload': u'true', u'monPolDn': u'', u'modTs': u'2017-02-24T00:50:47.373+00:00', u'uid': u'0', u'childAction': u''}}}, {u'nvoEp': {u'attributes': {u'status': u'', u'operState': u'down', u'persistentOnReload': u'true', u'propFaultBitmap': u'', u'hostReach': u'0', u'adminSt': u'disabled', u'holdUpTime': u'0', u'encapType': u'0', u'uid': u'0', u'epId': u'1', u'sourceInterface': u'unspecified', u'descr': u'', u'monPolDn': u'uni/fabric/monfab-default', u'modTs': u'2017-02-24T00:50:47.373+00:00', u'holdDownTimerExpiryTime': u'NA', u'autoRemapReplicationServers': u'no', u'operEncapType': u'0', u'dn': u'sys/epId-1', u'mac': u'00:00:00:00:00:00', u'cfgSrc': u'0', u'childAction': u'', u'vpcVIPNotified': u'no', u'learningMode': u'0', u'controllerId': u'0', u'holdUpTimerExpiryTime': u'NA', u'holdDownTime': u'180'}, u'children': [{u'nvoPeers': {u'attributes': {u'status': u'', u'persistentOnReload': u'true', u'monPolDn': u'', u'modTs': u'2017-02-24T00:50:47.373+00:00', u'uid': u'0', u'rn': u'peers', u'childAction': u''}}}, {u'nvoNws': {u'attributes': {u'status': u'', u'persistentOnReload': u'true', u'monPolDn': u'', u'modTs': u'2017-02-24T00:50:47.373+00:00', u'uid': u'0', u'rn': u'nws', u'childAction': u''}}}]}}], u'totalCount': u'3'}
```

So then I added `encode('utf-8')` to my print output statement and after that I got below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shandeep/Desktop/n9k-rest/Andys_payloads/Andys_script.py", line 548, in <module>
    get_interface_nve()
  File "/Users/shandeep/Desktop/n9k-rest/Andys_payloads/Andys_script.py", line 113, in get_interface_nve
    print(x.encode('utf-8'))
  AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Below is definition and function call.

```
def request_get(dn):
    cookie = login_api()
    response = requests.get(url + dn + '?query-target=subtree&rsp-subtree=full', cookies=cookie, verify=False)
    print('Valid response: \n' + response.text)
    return response.json()

def get_interface_nve():
    x = request_get('/api/mo/sys/epId-1.json')
    print('PRINT OUTPUT: \n')
    #print(x)
    print(x.encode('utf-8'))
```

Function call:

```
get_interface_nve()
```

Comment: That `u` merely indicates that the string keys are `unicode` objects. There is no actual `'u'` character there. Note, it is outside the quotes.

Comment: You are looking for: [Convert unicode string dictionary into dictionary in python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1254499/1165509)

Comment: @marcanuy No, that is not relevant.

Comment: No harm in having them!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga updated link.

Comment: @marcanuy but the OP hasn't indicated any reason to prefer `str` vs `unicode` types. Likely, they should just stick with the `unicode`

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga I figured out it was `unicode`, thats why I tried to convert it as I used to for `str`. But didnt know how to proceed with JSON output. @dsh gave a solution that worked.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Just common sense, it was 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`dict` objects do not have a method `encode()`.  That is a method for `str` objects.  The text you see is python's "repr" representation of a (unicode) string.  You only have it because you used the wrong approach to convert your dict to a string.

You need to convert your `dict` to JSON.  This is not achieved using `print()` or `repr()` or `str()`.  Use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) module for this.

Eg:

```
x = {u'imdata': [{u'nvoNws': {u'attributes': {u'dn': u'sys/epId-1/nws'}}}]}
json.dump(x, sys.stdout)
```

Comment: Why would they convert it back to JSON?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I have no idea. The question is asked, without context of the project in which it exists. It does seem strange to me to retrieve JSON, convert to dict, and convert to JSON.  That is partly why in my example I started with the dict object rather than JSON : )

Comment: maybe they're making a change to original json object? that's what i'm doing and why i'm on this stackoverflow question