# KeyError when parsing JSON python from boto3

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to read a **json** file from S3 bucket.

```
def getJSONObject(object):
    content = object.get()['Body'].read()[1:-1]
    content = '{' + content + '}'
    data = json.loads(content)
    return data
```

This converts my Streaming Body into a json content, using a very hacky way. My output is in the following format. Output of

```
print(data)

{u'DATE_TIME': u'2017/06/19 16:24:41', 
 u'S3_PATH': u'S3://hw-app-a5e2ccf910/DocumentProcessingVA/WPI1/WPE2043/EntityTaggingFinalOutput/c209201-1c04-49c3-ab4d-a7cc79d7f18d.json'}
```

However when I try to print the value passing the key, I get a key error

```
print(data["DATE_TIME"])
```

If I do this in a for loop by iterating through the keys and then printing, it is printing the value fine. i.e doing this

```
for info in data:
    print(data[info])
```

Is there a better way to do this, as I have larger JSON files, and would like to not execute a for loop every time to get only bits of data from it, when I should be able to use the key. I''m not sure if this is an encoding error or the way I have defined my function to get the JSON data.

P.S trying to load as a string from the Streaming Body output doesn't help

Comment: Is there really a space between the `u`s and the quotation marks?

Comment: Possibly an encoding issue,

Comment: @KlausD. No that was just an error when I was posting my bad

Comment: What is the output of `print(data)`?

Comment: @DeepSpace 
`{u'DATE_TIME': u'2017/06/19 16:24:41', 
 u'S3_PATH': u'S3://hw-app-a5e2ccf910/DocumentProcessingVA/WPI1/WPE2043/EntityTaggingFinalOutput/c209201-1c04-49c3-ab4d-a7cc79d7f18d.json'}`

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254454/fastest-way-to-convert-a-dicts-keys-values-from-unicode-to-str)

Comment: @Lexasaurus thank that helped a lot