# How do I convert a Python list into a C array by using ctypes?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

If I have the follow 2 sets of code, how do I glue them together?

```
void
c_function(void *ptr) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%p", ptr[i]);
    }

    return;
}


def python_routine(y):
    x = []
    for e in y:
        x.append(e)
```

How can I call the c_function with a contiguous list of elements in x?  I tried to cast x to a c_void_p, but that didn't work.

I also tried to use something like

```
x = c_void_p * 10 
for e in y:
    x[i] = e
```

but this gets a syntax error.

The C code clearly wants the address of an array.  How do I get this to happen?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The following code works on arbitrary lists:

```
import ctypes
py_values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr = (ctypes.c_int * len(py_values))(*py_values)
```

Comment: "*pyarr" in python... What does it mean?

Comment: @AaronYC I'm sorry for the confusion; `pyarr` is an ordinary python list, like `pyar = [1,2,3,4]`. If you're wondering about the star before the name, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/what-does-mean-in-python

Comment: Good answer, but a bit glib for us unwashed ones.

Comment: @Jiminion See my answer below for an explanation of the syntax.

Comment: Very well, now how would one free that `arr` variable ? Surely we don't have to use `free()` from C  here do we ?

Comment: What is the extension of this to produce a 2dim array for a given list like `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`?

Comment: @Vishal, you have to unpack for each dimension in the multidimension array case:`(ctypes.c_int*2*2)((ctypes.c_int*2)(1,2),(ctypes.c_int*2)(3,4))` but it is easier to use [numpy.ctypeslib.as_ctypes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html#module-numpy.ctypeslib)

Comment: I wonder if this leads to memory leak or not?

Answer (score 24):

This is an explanation of the accepted answer.

`ctypes.c_int * len(pyarr)` creates an array (sequence) of type `c_int` of length 4 ([python3](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations), [python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)). Since `c_int` is an object whose constructor takes one argument, `(ctypes.c_int * len(pyarr)(*pyarr)` does a one shot init of each `c_int` instance from `pyarr`. An [easier to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687170/how-to-insert-item-into-c-char-p-array) form is:

```
pyarr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
seq = ctypes.c_int * len(pyarr)
arr = seq(*pyarr)
```

Use `type` function to see the difference between `seq` and `arr`.

Answer (score 13):

From [the ctypes tutorial](http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html):

```
>>> IntArray5 = c_int * 5
>>> ia = IntArray5(5, 1, 7, 33, 99)
```

Comment: Try to create arrays more than with 255 items.

Comment: Works with more than 255 items: `IntArray300 = c_int * 300; 
arrayWith300Elements=IntArray300(*list([i for i in range(300)]))`

Answer (score 2):

```
import ctypes
import typing

def foo(aqs : typing.List[int]) -> ctypes.Array:
    array_type = ctypes.c_int64 * len(aqs)
    ans = array_type(*aqs)
    return ans

for el in foo([1,2,3]):
    print(el)
```

this will give:

```
1
2
3
```