# How to insert item into c_char_p array

Tags: python, ctypes

I want to pass **an array of char pointer** to a C function.

I refer to http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#arrays

I write the following code.

```
from ctypes import *

names = c_char_p * 4
# A 3 times for loop will be written here.
# The last array will assign to a null pointer.
# So that C function knows where is the end of the array.
names[0] = c_char_p('hello')
```

and I get the following error.

> TypeError: '_ctypes.PyCArrayType'
>   object does not support item
>   assignment

Any idea how I can resolve this? I want to interface with

```
c_function(const char** array_of_string);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you did was to create an array *type*, not an actual array, so basically:

```
import ctypes
array_type = ctypes.c_char_p * 4
names = array_type()
```

You can then do something along the lines of:

```
names[0] = "foo"
names[1] = "bar"
```

...and proceed to call your C function with the `names` array as parameter.