# How to convert a list of lists of floats in to a C double ** using ctypes in Python

Tags: python, ctypes

Im trying to convert a Python list of lists of floats into a C double ** ptr

```
lst = [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3]]
c_dbl_ptr = (ctypes.c_double * len(lst) * len(lst[0])) (*(tuple(tuple(sublist) for sublist in lst)))
```

Which yields `IndexError: invalid index`

This method is from [How do I convert a Python list of lists of lists into a C array by using ctypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434026/how-do-i-convert-a-python-list-of-lists-of-lists-into-a-c-array-by-using-ctypes) but it seems im doing something wrong when trying to apply it to a 2d list.

Comment: Try to debug this by separating that long second line into multiple lines. Also don't name your variable `list` because then you shadow the `list` function

Comment: What's the C Function prototype? It's actually a `double**` and not a `double*` to a 2D array? The latter is more common, and row and col size normally passed as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58262388/4788546, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58735157/4788546.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `double**` is an pointer to one or more `double*`, so each row of doubles needs to be in a double array, and each of those separate arrays used as initializers to a `double*` array:

```py
import ctypes as ct

lst = [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3]]

# Equivalent to C double* array[3].
# Ctypes passes as double** when passed to a C function.
pdbl_array = (ct.POINTER(ct.c_double) * len(lst))(*[(ct.c_double * len(n))(*n) for n in lst])
for pdbl in pdbl_array:
    print(pdbl[:4]) # since it is a pointer, must provide size.
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
[3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```

Maybe easier to read in steps, but not quite equivalent since it assumes all the sub-lists are the same length.  The former code supports variable length sub-lists.

```py
PDBL_ARRAY_TYPE = ct.POINTER(ct.c_double) * len(lst)  # (double*)[3] type
DBL_ARRAY_TYPE = ct.c_double * len(lst[0])  # double[4] type

# Python list of double[4] arrays using sublists as initializers
arrays = [DBL_ARRAY_TYPE(*sublst) for sublst in lst]

# ctypes (double*)[3] array using arrays as initializers
pdbl_array = PDBL_ARRAY_TYPE(*arrays)
```

If instead you really just need a 2D array, the original code had the array sizes reversed.  In `ctypes`, a C `double[3][4]` is declared with the sizes in reverse, e.g., `ctypes.c_double * 4 * 3`.  `4 * ctypes.c_double * 3` or `3 * (4 * ctypes.c_double)` also work.  Basically, the row multiplication has to happen first.

```py
import ctypes as ct

lst = [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3]]
dbl_2darray = (ct.c_double * len(lst[0]) * len(lst))(*(tuple(tuple(sublist) for sublist in lst)))
for arr in dbl_2darray:
    print(list(arr))
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
[3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your list comprehension. When applying this, you get a list of ctypes.c_double arrays. This is done by iterating over each array in the list (which I have renamed due to `list` being a method)

```py
import ctypes
lst = [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3]]
x = [(ctypes.c_double* len(sublst))(*sublst) for sublst in lst]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I need to convert into a double ** to pass it to a C function in a dll library, could i pass x as a double ** pointer? Thanks

Comment: @willaayy No, this answer is a *Python* list of three *ctypes* `double[4]` arrays.