# Python method/function arguments starting with asterisk and dual asterisk

Tags: python

I am not able understand where does these type of functions are used and how differently these arguments work from the normal arguments. I have encountered them many time but never got chance to understand them properly.

Ex:

```
def method(self, *links, **locks):
    #some foo
    #some bar
    return
```

I know i could have search the documentation but i have no idea what to search for.

Comment: See a prev question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287085/what-does-args-and-kwargs-mean

Comment: Ditto--here is a link that will help:  http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/

Comment: "I know i could have search the documentation but i have no idea what to search for." Happens all too often when learning. it would have been like saying "what's that thing in the stuff?" What some so-called "experts" forget is that sometimes tere's a minimum level of understanding require to know how the hell to ask a question.

Comment: You could be interested to read also one of the questions [What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for Python parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/2062965) or [What does asterisk * mean in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/400739/2062965)

Comment: such a good question!

Answer (score 125, accepted):

The `*args` and `**keywordargs` forms are used for passing lists of arguments and dictionaries of arguments, respectively. So if I had a function like this:

```
def printlist(*args):
    for x in args:
        print(x)
```

I could call it like this:

```
printlist(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  # or as many more arguments as I'd like
```

For this

```
def printdict(**kwargs):
    print(repr(kwargs))

printdict(john=10, jill=12, david=15)
```

`*args` behaves like a list, and `**keywordargs` behaves like a dictionary, but you don't have to explicitly pass a `list` or a `dict` to the function.

See [this](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) for more examples.

Comment: But *can* you explicitly pass a list or dict to the function?

Comment: Yes, you can. The list will be args[0] if you pass it "as is". In the other hand, f you call the function with an asterisk (not the one in the function definition, this is in the call) then, the passed list will BE THE actual args tuple.

Comment: *args is a `tuple`, not a `list`

Comment: >>> def d(*args):
...     print(type(args))
>>> d(1, 2, 3)
<type 'tuple'>