# Passing arguments  during Class Initialization

Tags: python

I am scratching my head on what is going in the following code.

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        print type(args)
        print args

j_dict = {'rmaNumber':1111, 'caseNo':2222} 
print type(j_dict)
p = foo(j_dict)
```

it yields :

```
<type 'dict'>
<type 'tuple'>
({'rmaNumber': 1111, 'caseNo': 2222},)
```

It seems to me that this code converts a dict to a tuple!! Can anyone explain this

Comment: Well, it's a tuple containing one element: a dict

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually it's because `args` is a `tuple` to hold a variable length argument list. `args[0]` is still your `dict` - no conversion has taken place.

See [this tutorial](http://basicpython.com/understanding-arguments-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) for further information about `args` and `kwargs` (the keyword version of args).

Answer (score 3):

When you use `*args`, all the positional arguments are "zipped" or "packed" in a tuple.

I you use `**kwargs`, all the keyword arguments are packed into a dictionary.

(Actually the names `args` or `kwargs` are irrelevant, what matters are the asterisks) **:-)**

For example:

```
>>> def hello(* args):
...     print "Type of args (gonna be tuple): %s, args: %s" % (type(args), args)
... 
>>> hello("foo", "bar", "baz")
Type of args (gonna be tuple): <type 'tuple'>, args: ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

Now, this wouldn't happen if you didn't "pack" those args.

```
>>> def hello(arg1, arg2, arg3):
...     print "Type of arg1: %s, arg1: %s" % (type(arg1), arg1)
...     print "Type of arg2: %s, arg2: %s" % (type(arg2), arg2)
...     print "Type of arg3: %s, arg3: %s" % (type(arg3), arg3)
... 
>>> hello("foo", "bar", "baz")
Type of arg1: <type 'str'>, arg1: foo
Type of arg2: <type 'str'>, arg2: bar
Type of arg3: <type 'str'>, arg3: baz
```

You can also refer to this question [Python method/function arguments starting with asterisk and dual asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306574/python-method-function-arguments-starting-with-asterisk-and-dual-asterisk)