# Matrix Transpose in Python

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a matrix transpose function for python but I can't seem to make it work.
Say I have

```
theArray = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
```

and I want my function to come up with

```
newArray = [['a','d','g'],['b','e','h'],['c', 'f', 'i']]
```

So in other words, if I were to print this 2D array as columns and rows I would like the rows to turn into columns and columns into rows.

I made this so far but it doesn't work

```
def matrixTranspose(anArray):
    transposed = [None]*len(anArray[0])
    for t in range(len(anArray)):
        for tt in range(len(anArray[t])):
            transposed[t] = [None]*len(anArray)
            transposed[t][tt] = anArray[tt][t]
    print transposed
```

Answer (score 347, accepted):

Python 2:

```
>>> theArray = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
>>> zip(*theArray)
[('a', 'd', 'g'), ('b', 'e', 'h'), ('c', 'f', 'i')]
```

Python 3:

```
>>> [*zip(*theArray)]
[('a', 'd', 'g'), ('b', 'e', 'h'), ('c', 'f', 'i')]
```

Comment: if you're going to iterate through the results, `izip` from `itertools` can save memory for large arrays.

Comment: How would you have it return a list for the sub lists? Like `[['a', 'b', 'g'], ['d', 'e', 'h'], ['c', 'f', 'i']]` instead of `[('a', 'd', 'g'), ('b', 'e', 'h'), ('c', 'f', 'i')]`?

Comment: @acollection_: `map(list, zip(*theArray))`.

Comment: Why the asterisk?

Comment: @user3728501 [What does asterisk * mean in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/400739/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I read that but unfortunately I didn't understand any of it

Comment: @user3728501 have you just read the question, its duplicate and their more than a dozen answers in 8 minutes? Or have you seen them before? [The argument unpacking is discussed even in the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). If it is still unclear; pick an answer that you understand the most and ask a separate question about the unclear parts.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins This is not needed with Python 3.0 and above. There, `zip` already returns an iterator: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists

Comment: @xuiqzy It's not that I'm not aware of it, but that's true.

Answer (score 68):

```
>>> theArray = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
>>> [list(i) for i in zip(*theArray)]
[['a', 'd', 'g'], ['b', 'e', 'h'], ['c', 'f', 'i']]
```

the list generator creates a new 2d array with list items instead of tuples.

Comment: This is the way to go if you want to assign the result to a variable (as opposed to, e.g., iterating over it directly) — assuming you want lists instead of tuples, as mentioned.

Comment: Another option (as implied by the comments in the accepted answer) would be: `list(map(list, zip(*theArray)))`

Answer (score 42):

If your rows are not equal you can also use `map`:

```
>>> uneven = [['a','b','c'],['d','e'],['g','h','i']]
>>> map(None,*uneven)
[('a', 'd', 'g'), ('b', 'e', 'h'), ('c', None, 'i')]
```

Edit: In Python 3 the functionality of `map` changed, `itertools.zip_longest` can be used instead:
  Source: [What’s New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> uneven = [['a','b','c'],['d','e'],['g','h','i']]
>>> list(itertools.zip_longest(*uneven))
[('a', 'd', 'g'), ('b', 'e', 'h'), ('c', None, 'i')]
```

Answer (score 20):

Much easier with numpy:

```
>>> arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> arr
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> arr.T
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])
>>> theArray = np.array([['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']])
>>> theArray 
array([['a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['d', 'e', 'f'],
       ['g', 'h', 'i']], 
      dtype='|S1')
>>> theArray.T
array([['a', 'd', 'g'],
       ['b', 'e', 'h'],
       ['c', 'f', 'i']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem with your original code was that you initialized `transpose[t]` at every element, rather than just once per row:

```
def matrixTranspose(anArray):
    transposed = [None]*len(anArray[0])
    for t in range(len(anArray)):
        transposed[t] = [None]*len(anArray)
        for tt in range(len(anArray[t])):
            transposed[t][tt] = anArray[tt][t]
    print transposed
```

This works, though there are more Pythonic ways to accomplish the same things, including @J.F.'s `zip` application.

Comment: Note that this implementation doesn't work with matrices that have different numbers of columns and rows

Answer (score 5):

To complete J.F. Sebastian's answer, if you have a list of lists with different lengths, check out [this great post from ActiveState](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/410687-transposing-a-list-of-lists-with-different-lengths/). In short:

> The built-in function zip does a similar job, but truncates the result
>   to the length of the shortest list, so some elements from the original
>   data may be lost afterwards.

To handle list of lists with different lengths, use:

```
def transposed(lists):
   if not lists: return []
   return map(lambda *row: list(row), *lists)

def transposed2(lists, defval=0):
   if not lists: return []
   return map(lambda *row: [elem or defval for elem in row], *lists)
```

Comment: That's good catch. However, matrices doesn't have lists with different lengths.

Comment: It depends on how they are stored.

Answer (score 5):

The "best" answer has already been submitted, but I thought I would add that you can use nested list comprehensions, as seen in the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions).

Here is how you could get a transposed array:

```
def matrixTranspose( matrix ):
    if not matrix: return []
    return [ [ row[ i ] for row in matrix ] for i in range( len( matrix[ 0 ] ) ) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

This one will preserve rectangular shape, so that subsequent transposes will get the right result:

```
import itertools
def transpose(list_of_lists):
  return list(itertools.izip_longest(*list_of_lists,fillvalue=' '))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this with list comprehension like the following

`matrix = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
n = len(matrix)
transpose = [[row[i] for row in matrix] for i in range(n)]
print (transpose)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transpose a matrix like A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]),  then you can simply use A.T, but for a vector like a = [1,2], a.T  does not return a transpose! and you need to use a.reshape(-1, 1),  as below

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2])
print('a.T not transposing Python!\n','a = ',a,'\n','a.T = ', a.T)
print('Transpose of vector a is: \n',a.reshape(-1, 1))

A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
print('Transpose of matrix A is: \n',A.T)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do it simply using python comprehension.

```py
arr = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
    ['d', 'e', 'f'], 
    ['g', 'h', 'i']
]
transpose = [[arr[y][x] for y in range(len(arr))] for x in range(len(arr[0]))]
```

Comment: Although this may be a correct answer. Two lines of code isn't very useful without an explanation of what and how it solves the original question. Please provide details to your answer.

Comment: when posting a new answer to an old question, expectations are high. Please don't post an inferior solution to the ones already posted

Answer (score -1):

```
def matrixTranspose(anArray):
  transposed = [None]*len(anArray[0])

  for i in range(len(transposed)):
    transposed[i] = [None]*len(transposed)

  for t in range(len(anArray)):
    for tt in range(len(anArray[t])):            
        transposed[t][tt] = anArray[tt][t]
  return transposed

theArray = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]

print matrixTranspose(theArray)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import  numpy as np #Import Numpy 

m=int(input("Enter row")) #Input Number of row

n=int(input("Enter column")) #Input number of column

a=[] #Blank Matrix

for i in range(m): #Row Input

    b=[] #Blank List

    for j in range(n):#column Input

        j=int(input("Enter Number in Pocket ["+str(i)+"]["+str(j)+"]")) #sow Row Column Number 

        b.append(j) #addVlaue to list

    a.append(b)#Add List To Matrix

a=np.array(a)#convert 1matrix as Numpy

b=a.transpose()#transpose Using Numpy

print(a) #Print Matrix 

print(b)#print Transpose Matrix
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#generate matrix
matrix=[]
m=input('enter number of rows, m = ')
n=input('enter number of columns, n = ')
for i in range(m):
    matrix.append([])
    for j in range(n):
        elem=input('enter element: ')
        matrix[i].append(elem)

#print matrix
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        print matrix[i][j],
    print '\n'

#generate transpose
transpose=[]
for j in range(n):
    transpose.append([])
    for i in range (m):
        ent=matrix[i][j]
        transpose[j].append(ent)

#print transpose
for i in range (n):
    for j in range (m):
        print transpose[i][j],
    print '\n'
```

Answer (score -3):

```
a=[]
def showmatrix (a,m,n):
    for i in range (m):
        for j in range (n):
            k=int(input("enter the number")
            a.append(k)      
print (a[i][j]),

print('\t')


def showtranspose(a,m,n):
    for j in range(n):
        for i in range(m):
            print(a[i][j]),
        print('\t')

a=((89,45,50),(130,120,40),(69,79,57),(78,4,8))
print("given matrix of order 4x3 is :")
showmatrix(a,4,3)


print("Transpose matrix is:")
showtranspose(a,4,3)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
def transpose(matrix):
   x=0
   trans=[]
   b=len(matrix[0])
   while b!=0:
       trans.append([])
       b-=1
   for list in matrix:
       for element in list:
          trans[x].append(element)
          x+=1
       x=0
   return trans
```

Answer (score -3):

```
def transpose(matrix):
    listOfLists = []
    for row in range(len(matrix[0])):
        colList = []
        for col in range(len(matrix)):
            colList.append(matrix[col][row])
    listOfLists.append(colList)

    return listOfLists
```

Comment: Its a simple implementation for a transpose, though there are libraries like mentioned in other answers are also available.

Answer (score -3):

`

```html
def transpose(m):
    return(list(map(list,list(zip(*m)))))
```

`This function will return the transpose

Answer (score -3):

Python Program to transpose matrix:

```
row,col = map(int,input().split())
matrix = list()

for i in range(row):
    r = list(map(int,input().split()))
    matrix.append(r)

trans = [[0 for y in range(row)]for x in range(col)]

for i in range(len(matrix[0])):
    for j in range(len(matrix)):
        trans[i][j] = matrix[j][i]     

for i in range(len(trans)):
    for j in range(len(trans[0])):
        print(trans[i][j],end=' ')
    print(' ')
```

Comment: This is not useful!