# How would I succinctly transpose nested lists?

Tags: python

I am writing code to parse a tilemap map from a config file. The map is in the format:

```
1|2|3|4
1|2|3|4
2|3|4|5
```

where the numbers represent tiles.
I then make this into an integer array:

```
[[int(tile) for tile in row.split("|")] for row in  "1|2|3|4\n1|2|3|4\n2|3|4|5".lstrip("\n").split("\n")]
```

This produces an array in the format [row][column], but I would prefer it to be [column][row] as in [x][y] so I wouldn't have to address it backwards (i.e. [y][x]).
But I can't think of any concise ways of attacking the problem. 
I have considered reworking the format using xml syntax through Tiled, but it appears too difficult for a beginner.

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matrix Transpose in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

use `mylist = zip(*mylist)`:

```
>>> original = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
>>> transposed = zip(*original)
>>> transposed
    [(1, 1, 2), (2, 2, 3), (3, 3, 4), (4, 4, 5)]

>>> original[2][3]
    5

>>> transposed[3][2]
    5
```

How it works:  [`zip(*original)`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) is equal to `zip(original[0], original[1], original[2])`.  which in turn is equal to: zip([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]).

Comment: That's an amazingly efficient way of doing it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
def listTranspose( x ):
    """ Interpret list of lists as a matrix and transpose """ 
    tups = zip( *x )
    return [ list(t) for t in tups ]
```