# Python3.4 - enumeration through columns then rows in csv to obtain Max lengths

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to find the Max length for each column in a tab delimited csv file.
I can find the max value of one column by using this:

```
import csv
oldlen=0
with open(mfile) as csvfile:
test = csv.reader(csvfile,dialect='excel-tab')
for row in test:
    if len(row[0]) > oldlen:
        newlen = len(row[0])
print (newlen)
```

If I wish to do all columns (and count them), I could just change row[] manually, but I wish to learn so I tried this:

```
with open(mfile) as csvfile:
test = csv.reader(csvfile,dialect='excel-tab')
ncol=len(test[0])
for column in test:
    for row in test:
        if len(row[column]) > oldlen:
            newlen = len(row[0])
    print (column,newlen)
```

Which, of course, doesnt make programatic sense. But it indicates, I hope, what my intention is. I have to do the columns first so I can get the max length out of each column, across all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `dict` to store a column number->max length lookup and assign to that by looping over each column of each row.

```
lengths = {}
with open(mfile) as csvfile:
    test = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel-tab')
    for row in test:
        for colno, col in enumerate(row):
            lengths[colno] = max(len(col), lengths.get(colno, 0))
```

The number of columns will be `len(lengths)`, and the maximum length of each will be accessible as `lengths[0]` for the first column `lengths[1]` for the second etc...

Comment: It works, but I'm confused over the colno,col  - How does it know to go through columns ? are these reserved words?

Comment: @jer99 think of a file as an iterable of rows... each row is itself iterable, so iterating over a row, is going through each column in that row... There's no reserved words... you can name them what you want - I opted for `colno` (column number) and `col` (column value)

Comment: So the list automatically contains and index and a value. So I tried a statement like "...for rowid, row in test:"  and it says there are too many values to unpack (expected 2). Thats a bit confusing to me.  I'm assuming that "test" is a list with a index and value as well.

Comment: @jer99 the [enumerate function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) returns a tuple of index and value... iterating over a list directly only gives the values...

Answer (score 1):

You can [transpose the rows into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313194/how-would-i-succinctly-transpose-nested-lists) with the `zip()` function:

```
with open(mfile) as csvfile:
    test = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel-tab')
    columns = list(zip(*test))
```

and then get the maximum value per column:

```
for col in columns:
    print(max(col))
```