# appending to a 2D list in python where the row/col length is unknown

Tags: python, list, grid, 2d, append

I am looking to flip the rows and columns on a 2D list and am running into trouble.  Python won't allow a value to be assigned to an uninitialized 'cell'.  I am not sure how to initialize my grid since I don't know the length ahead of time.  The following:

```
data = list()
maReader = csv.reader(open('TEST.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for rindex, row in enumerate(maReader):
    for iindex, item in enumerate(row):
        data[iindex][rindex] = item
```

fails with a "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" error.  I could loop through twice, the first time to count columns and rows, than initialize the grid, than loop again and assign values, but that seems awfully wasteful.

I am pretty new to Python and figure there is a simple way to do this that I am missing.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp) counterpoint to @retracile's [LBYL](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-lbyl) approach.

```
data = [] #list()
maReader = csv.reader(open('TEST.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for rindex, row in enumerate(maReader):
    for iindex, item in enumerate(row):
        try:
            data[iindex].append(item)
        except IndexError:
            data.append([item])
```

Comment: Since the first row is the only one to hit the exception, this approach is probably faster than mine.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all rows of equal length, you can approach it like this:

```
data = list()
maReader = csv.reader(open('TEST.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for rindex, row in enumerate(maReader):
    for iindex, item in enumerate(row):
        if len(data) <= iindex:
            data.append([])
        data[iindex].append(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
maReader = csv.reader(open('TEST.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
data = zip(*maReader)
```

Though, `zip` gives a list of tuples. If you need a list of lists you can do either of these:

```
data = [list(x) for x in zip(*maReader)]
data = map(list, zip(*maReader))
```

Comment: I _knew_ there was a better way, but my brain just wasn't working.  +1

Answer (score 1):

if all rows of equal length then `data = zip(*maReader)` should do it.
If not:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

list(izip_longest(*f, fillvalue=''))
```

See also [Matrix Transpose in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4937491/).