# Python3 reading data from cvs file: Converting columns to Lists

Tags: python, csv

I am using Python to read a cvs file. The CSV file has two columns separated by ','. I am only able to read one column and when i try to create a list for the next column, I am getting a blank list.

My code is as follow:

```
import csv
with open('exdata1.csv') as inputData:
    data = csv.reader(inputData, delimiter=',')
    xVal = [row[0] for row in data]
    yVal = [row[1] for row in data]
```

The output is like this:

```
>>> xVal
['6.1101', '5.5277', '8.5186', '7.0032', '5.8598', '8.3829', '7.4764', '8.5781', '6.4862', '5.0546', '5.7107', '14.164', '5.734', '8.4084', '5.6407', '5.3794', '6.3654', '5.1301', '6.4296', '7.0708', '6.1891', '20.27', '5.4901', '6.3261', '5.5649', '18.945', '12.828', '10.957', '13.176', '22.203', '5.2524', '6.5894', '9.2482', '5.8918', '8.2111', '7.9334', '8.0959', '5.6063', '12.836', '6.3534', '5.4069', '6.8825', '11.708', '5.7737', '7.8247', '7.0931', '5.0702', '5.8014', '11.7', '5.5416', '7.5402', '5.3077', '7.4239', '7.6031', '6.3328', '6.3589', '6.2742', '5.6397', '9.3102', '9.4536', '8.8254', '5.1793', '21.279', '14.908', '18.959', '7.2182', '8.2951', '10.236', '5.4994', '20.341', '10.136', '7.3345', '6.0062', '7.2259', '5.0269', '6.5479', '7.5386', '5.0365', '10.274', '5.1077', '5.7292', '5.1884', '6.3557', '9.7687', '6.5159', '8.5172', '9.1802', '6.002', '5.5204', '5.0594', '5.7077', '7.6366', '5.8707', '5.3054', '8.2934', '13.394', '5.4369']
>>> yVal
[]
```

I am not sure what exactly to google for this issue. Any tutorial which deals with this?

Comment: Could you attach part or your `exdata1.csv` file?

Comment: What should the second column contain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`csv.reader()` objects read data from the underlying file object, and file objects have file positions that move from start to end as you read. If you want to read *again* you need to rewind the file pointer to the start:

```
xVal = [row[0] for row in data]
inputData.seek(0)
yVal = [row[1] for row in data]
```

However, you'd be better of reading just *once*, and [transposing the rows to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507104/row-to-column-transposition-in-python):

```
xVal, yVal = zip(*data)[:2]
```

Comment: could you please explain `xVal, yVal = zip(*data)[:2]` ?

Comment: @Morpheus: I just edited in a link to a post that explains this. Basically, you apply all the rows as separate arguments to the `zip()` function, which then pairs up the first value of each row as one list, the second value of each row as another, etc.

Comment: @Morpheus: the resulting list of columns is then sliced to only take the first two columns (in case you have more than 2) and assigns those two columns to the variables `xVal` and `yVal`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just saw the link.

Comment: You could expand this out to `columns = zip(*data)`, then `xVal = columns[0]` and `yVal = columns[1]`. But why use 3 lines when you have tuple assignment..

Comment: Suppose I have 4 columns, then the [:2] will become [:4]? Are we saying that assign first column to xVal, assign second column to yVal till you reach index 3?

Comment: @Morpheus: yes, you can slice it to more columns, so `[:4]` gives you the first four and you can assign those to four different variables. *Or* you could just use a single `columns` variable and refer to `columns[0]` and `columns[1]`, etc.

Comment: I am getting the type error when i try to do xVal = columns[0]. `TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable`. I think in python3 zip gives a different object

Comment: Hey! you have to convert it into a list. So the final form is
`xVal, yVal = list(zip(*data))[:2]`

Comment: @Morpheus: right, yes, `zip()` in Python 3 returns a generator. Use `xVal = next(columns); yVal = next(columns)`, or use `columns = list(zip(*data))`, or use a `itertools.islice()` object to do the slicing.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to use Pandas and read CSV as a data frame, then you could quickly access columns as Numpy arrays. Code example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('exdata1.csv', header=None, names=['One', 'Two'])
print(df)

print(df.One)
print(df.Two)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a solution which didn't depend on bumpy or pandas.

Answer (score 0):

you can change this line in your code `data = csv.reader(inputData, delimiter=',')` by this one `data = list(csv.reader(inputData, delimiter=','))`.

This will create list that you can re-use as much as you want.