# How to map the column wise data in flowfile in NiFi?

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-nifi

i have csv file which having following structure.,

```
Alfreds,Centro,Ernst,Island,Bacchus
Germany,Mexico,Austria,UK,Canada
01,02,03,04,05
```

Now i have to move that data into database like below.

```
Name,City,ID
Alfreds,Germay,01
Centro,Mexico,02
Ernst,Austria,03
Island,UK,04
Bacchus,Canda,05
```

i try to map those colums but i can't able to extract the data in column wise.

Here my input data in column wise but i need to insert those in row wise in SQLServer

Can anyone suggest way to transfer column wise data into row wise in sql server?.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Andy,

It could be possible in NiFi also without using ExecuteScript.

I have extract the 3 input rows as input.1,input.2,input.3 in ExtractText. And then count number of columns in "input.1" using AnydelinateValues in [expression language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#anydelineatedvalue) and store that in **"TotalCount"** Attribute.

Initially made "Count=1".

Using Loop Concept to get the first column by using "Count" and then increment "Count" Check "Count" in RouteOnAttribute
"le(totalcount)"

Now form insert Query with **"Count"** Attribute.

It worked well for me.It could be useful for someone.

Comment: This will not scale well and will load the entire content of the flowfile into heap space -- a flowfile with thousands of rows will likely overflow your heap.

Comment: yes andy.It have occupies heap space.For large scale those method doesn't applicable it can affect heap memory.

Answer (score 2):

There is no existing Apache NiFi processor to perform column transposition. One of the problems is that this is difficult to do in a streaming manner, as most NiFi components are designed, because in a naïve implementation you need to hold the entire contents of the flowfile in active memory at the same time.

I would recommend using an `ExecuteScript` processor to do this ([here's a 6 line Python example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10507199/70465)). Be careful doing this because you can easily end up overflowing your heap if it is not set properly/you read unexpectedly large files into memory.

You could write a custom processor which performs a streaming transpose operation by iterating over each of *n* rows and reading up to your delimiter, storing a byte counter per row, combining the *n* elements as a single output row, and repeating the process starting from the respective byte counter of each row. (Given *m* columns, this is `O(m * n)`).

Another solution would be splitting the CSV input into individual rows using the `SplitText` processor, using an `ExecuteScript` or custom processor to transpose a single row into a single column, and then using a custom merge operation (either extend the existing `MergeContent` processor or write a script to do this) which laterally concatenates the incoming columns into a reconstructed matrix. (`O(n) + O(n) + O(m)` => `O(2n + m)` but the individual transposition operations can be performed in parallel so with *x* threads it's `O(n + n/x + m)`).

Any of these approaches will require some level of custom development. If you are really hesitant to pursue that, you could try using `ExecuteStreamCommand` and one of the [many `bash` solutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79642/transposing-rows-and-columns) to do the transposition on the command-line.