# Pivoting a csv data using Nifi processors

Tags: python, csv, apache-nifi

Is there any way of pivoting csv data just using NiFi processors.I have tried pivoting by wrting a python code using ExecuteScript processor.

But I want to know whether there is any easy way to pivot csv data other than coding.

csv data sample:

```
a,41,71,jjj
a,42,72,jjj
a,43,73,jjj
a,44,74,jjj
b,41,81,kkk
b,42,82,kkk
b,43,83,kkk
b,44,84,kkk
...........
```

Required pivot format is:

```
a,71,72,73,74,jjj
b,81,82,83,84,kkk
.................
```

Though pivoting can be achieved easily through Hive,there is also no access to Hive,HBase or Spark.

Any answers would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing this as you are with Python (or another language) in the `ExecuteScript` processor, but I have listed a couple other options in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42639228/70465).

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I prefer using python code for pivoting data using ExecuteScript processor.