# Two assignments in single python list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

For example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
x = [2*i for i in a]
y = [3*i for i in a]
```

Would it be more efficient to combine the list comprehensions into one (if possible) if the size of a is large? If so, how do you do this?

Something like,

```
x,y = [2*i, 3*i for i in a]
```

which doesn't work.  If using list comprehension is not more computationally efficient than using a normal for loop, let me know too.  Thanks.

Comment: The latter list comprehension returns a list of tuples, which you then  try to assign to a single tuple, which is why this fails. You could flatten this into two separate lists afterwards, but I can't say which is more efficient.

Comment: you can think of converting a list of pairs to a pair of lists as [transposing a 2D matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4937491/4279).

Comment: @user1473483 what about `x,y=[[2*i for i in a],[3*i for i in a]]` ??

Comment: Efficiency doesn't matter much here (since looping is cheap), but your question would make sense if `a` were a generator that should be only consumed once.

Comment: or 'xy = [(2*i, 3*i) for i in a]'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When in doubt about efficiency use the timeit module, it's always easy to use:

```
import timeit

def f1(aRange):
    x = [2*i for i in aRange]
    y = [3*i for i in aRange]
    return x,y

def f2(aRange):
    x, y = zip(*[(2*i, 3*i) for i in aRange])
    return x,y

def f3(aRange):
    x, y = zip(*((2*i, 3*i) for i in aRange))
    return x,y

def f4(aRange):
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in aRange:
        x.append(i*2)
        y.append(i*3)
    return x,y

print "f1: %f" %timeit.Timer("f1(range(100))", "from __main__ import f1").timeit(100000)
print "f2: %f" %timeit.Timer("f2(range(100))", "from __main__ import f2").timeit(100000)
print "f3: %f" %timeit.Timer("f3(range(100))", "from __main__ import f3").timeit(100000)
print "f4: %f" %timeit.Timer("f4(range(100))", "from __main__ import f4").timeit(100000)
```

The results seem to be consistent in pointing to the first option as the quickest.

```
f1: 2.127573
f2: 3.551838
f3: 3.859768
f4: 4.282406
```

Comment: This is a very good point. I would argue that the first option is probably the clearest as well as the fastest. The only time where this would be preferred would be if `aRange` were a generator that became exhausted, where using this method would avoid having to use `tee()` or a temporary list.

Answer (score 13):

You want to use [the `zip()` builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) with the star operator to do this. `zip()` normally turns to lists into a list of pairs, when used like this, it unzips - taking a list of pairs and splitting into two lists.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x, y = zip(*[(2*i, 3*i) for i in a])
>>> x
(2, 4, 6)
>>> y
(3, 6, 9)
```

Note that I'm not sure this is really any more efficient in a way that is going to matter.

Comment: You could use a generator instead of list comprehension here. `x, y = zip(*((2*i, 3*i) for i in a))` (if it makes any difference)

Comment: @jadkik94 As you are going to be using all the values anyway with zip, it's pretty much going to make no difference, although what you say is true.

Comment: @jadkik94 that seems to be the slowest option, check my answer.

Comment: @Lattyware I was actually surprised it even works, unpacking a generator... so I thought I'd share it :) turns out it's slower :(

Comment: @jadkik94: I believe the main advantage a generator has over building a temporary container is that it requires less memory. Sounds like it's the perennial memory vs speed trade-off...

Comment: It's just a matter of the process of getting an item from the generator (taking the item, then freezing the process, carrying on) is a lot more work than iterating through a list (add one to the index we are on), so a list will be faster, provided preallocating isn't very slow. In this case, the unpacking will take all the values anyway, so a list comp is just as good. Of course, for any non-trivial generator, that extra cost in processing becomes completely irrelevant.