# Transpose of a Matrix

Tags: python, matrix, list-comprehension

I'm trying to find the transpose of a matrix in python without actually using the size of the matrix.

I need to use list comprehensions to do something like [[row[i] for row in test] for i in range(n)] where test is a nxn matrix without actually using n.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4937491/395857 ?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt My question differs from that one in that I specify that I need a list comprehension and without using the size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `test` is a matrix represented by a list of lists, then

```
zip(*test)
```

is the transpose. For example,

```
In [16]: t = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

In [17]: t
Out[17]: [[1, 2, 3], 
          [4, 5, 6]]

In [18]: zip(*t)
Out[18]: [(1, 4), 
          (2, 5), 
          (3, 6)]
```

(The output has been formatted to show the result more clearly).

To understand `zip(*t)` first study [how `zip` works](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip), and then study [argument unpacking](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/). It is somewhat of a mind-bender, but once you see how it works, you'll be an expert at both concepts and the effect is quite pleasing.

---

There is no reason to use list comprehension here, but here is how you could do it anyway:

```
In [21]: [[row[i] for row in t] for i in range(len(t[1]))]
Out[21]: [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

(`len(t[1])` gives the number of columns.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `zip` and `*`:

```
>>> list(zip(*[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]))
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

list comprehension can help as written below:

```
def transpose(matrix):
    return [[row[col] for row in matrix] for col in range(len(matrix[0]))]
```