# python zip() function for a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy, zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matrix Transpose in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python)

I have a matrix, say

```
A = [[0,0],[1,1]]
```

and I would like to zip its components to have

```
(0,1),(0,1)
```

With two rows in A, this can be obtained easily with

```
zip(A[0],A[1])
```

What if I have a matrix A of any dimension

```
A = [[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]]
```

How to zip a sequence of elements?

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: This is called matrix transposition. See the above duplicate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `zip(*A)`.

```
>>> zip(*A)
[(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 2)]
```