# List of growing sum as a one-liner possible?

Tags: python, functional-programming, generator, list-comprehension

I'd like to sum up an iterable of integers and yield the growing sum for each element.  This is a simple thing using iterative programming:

```
def growingSum(elements):
  sum = 0
  for element in elements:
    sum += element
    yield sum
```

But can it be done in a functional way without the use of a variable, so probably as a one-liner using comprehensions?

Comment: `itertools.accumulate()`... but this is a duplicate, I'm afraid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cumulative addition whilst looping over a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879390/cumulative-addition-whilst-looping-over-a-list)

Comment: No, it's more a question about the core language and it's possibilities.  By presenting an implementation in the question I think I displayed awareness of the iterative solution which is implemented also in `accumulate()`.  This only refers to a library which implements a solution which does not fit my conditions.

Answer (score 3):

On Python3.2+ you can use [`itertools.accumulate`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> list(accumulate(range(10)))
[0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45]
```

Comment: The implementation of `accumulate()` does not fit my conditions, but thanks for that pointer.  In case I want to spare me the writing of the five lines in my question, I will use that instead ;-)  But my question really was more on an academical level.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this generator expression works:

```
((globals().__setitem__('__acc', globals()['__acc'] + x), globals()['__acc'])[1] for x in (globals().__setitem__('__acc', 0), iterable)[1])
```

(I'm not sure whether this is portable. It might rely on implementation-defined behavior.)

Alternatively, if one local may be introduced:

```
v = [0]
((v.append(v.pop() + x), v[0])[1] for x in iterable)
```

In any case, persons caught using such code will be shot. It is a massive hack and an affront to readability and common sense, without the slightest sign of justification or appeal.

Comment: Wow.  Using `setitem()` to make the use of a variable look like a functional approach.  That's ugly as hell.  ⁺¹ for that.

Comment: I just found: `v=[]` followed by `[ len(v.__iadd__(x*[0])) for x in [23,42,78,101] ]`.  What do you think? ;-)

Comment: @Alfe If introducing a local variable in a separate statement is allowed, I can do much better (will edit). I assumed that's prohibited :-) Your version has the huge disadvantage of essentially counting in unary, i.e. it takes time and memory proportional to the sum, rather than to the number of summands. `sum(v.__iadd__([x])) ...` fixes that, but is still quadratic in the number of summands.

Comment: My suggestion was just for fun.  But maybe it's a good idea to state the problems with that as well.

Comment: Btw, I have no problem with using variables in order to avoid repetition of code; it just should not use it for iteratively summing up the numbers.