# How to change the major order of lists in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of N lists, each sub-list containing M elements.

How do I create a list of M lists with N elements each, containing the n-th elements from the initial lists?

Let's say I have this

```
myList = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]
```

I want to have

```
[[1, 4],[2, 5],[3, 6]]
```

Performance is also important. I have sublists of millions of elements (though, one dimension will always be small: like 1.000.000 x 8 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give tuples, but it's trivial to extend this to contain lists:

```
zip(*myList)
```

i.e.

```
[list(i) for i in zip(*myList)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> zip(*lst)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

[`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) returns a list in Python 2, but an iterator in Python 3, which you have to convert to a list if you need to (`list(zip(lst))`)

See also: [Matrix Transpose in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4937491/1907098), [Transpose/Unzip Function (inverse of zip)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/a-transpose-unzip-function-in-python)

---

What `zip(*lst)` does is *unpacks* the elements of `lst` using the `*` operator into separate arguments of the `zip` function.

We know what happens when we put two lists in:

```
>>> zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

So if we have a list containing those two lists, the `*` will unpack the list to form two separate arguments - the equivalent of the above call.

```
>>> zip(*[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
myList = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]] 
zip(*myList )
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with the help of [itertools.izip()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip)

```
itertools.izip(*myList)
```

To create lists from  this iterator do the following:

```
map(list, itertools.izip(*myList))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned efficiency, I tried these with [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) and somewhere around 100x1000 they start to be better than `zip` (on CPython however they are worse):

```
myList = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]
newList = [[] for _ in xrange(len(myList[0]))]
    for innerList in myList:
        for elIdx in xrange(len(innerList)):
            newList[elIdx].append(innerList[elIdx])

print newList
```

And my first attempt (which is worse), but still better then `zip` on PyPy:

```
newList = [[None for i in xrange(len(myList))] for j in xrange(len(myList[0]))]
for i in xrange(len(myList)):
    for j in xrange(len(myList[i])):
        newList[j][i] = myList[i][j]

print newList
```

Comment: This is not more perfomant than using builtins in Python 2. For the test data `[range(1000000) for i in xrange(8)]` this code executes in 3 seconds on my system while my code takes 1.8 seconds. If you don't build lists but stick with tuples instead it is done in 0.26 seconds.

Comment: @filmor You are right, I was running it with PyPy and interestingly enough somewhere around 100x1000 these turn out to be faster than `zip` (tuple or list). I could post some numbers if you want.

Comment: This is indeed interesting, seems like PyPy is optimising better than the C compiler in this case ;)