# Printing lines vertically in python (not as list)

Tags: python, line

I would like to print strings vertically. I am not sure how do it when it is not in the form of lists... I referred to the izip but guess that works only for lists???

```
Input
Output 
Variable
Constant
```

I initially had the above as a list and then I did

```
List = ['Input', 'Output', 'Variable', 'Constant')
for entry in List.strip().split(','):
    nospace_list = entry.lstrip()
    print nospace_list
```

The output of the above code is what I have given and now I want to display that as

```
I O V C
n u a o
p t r n
u p i s
t u a t
  t b a
    l n
    e t
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920468/how-do-i-print-this-list-vertically

Comment: `print "\n".join(" ".join(x) for x in izip_longest(*List,fillvalue=" "))`

Comment: Hi this print it out vertically one below the other and not adjacent to each other...

Comment: Hi sorry about the previous comment. This actually worked.. Initially I had the strings as separate lists and once I made them as single list it worked

Answer (score 1):

You seemed interested in writing your own algorithm for this so here is a (much less efficient) way to do it without using `izip_longest()`:

```
>>> words = ['Input', 'Output', 'Variable', 'Constant']
>>> longest = max(len(word) for word in words)
>>> for i in range(longest):
...     print ' '.join(word.ljust(longest)[i] for word in words)
... 
I O V C
n u a o
p t r n
u p i s
t u a t
  t b a
    l n
    e t
```

This works by padding each word with spaces to the length of the longest word and then printing each letter from each word.