# Pythonic iteration over multiple lists in parallel

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x, data-structures

I'd like to know an elegant, Pythonic way to iterate over a list of lists (or dict of lists) **in parallel** in Python 3. The number of lists is not known until runtime, so I believe I cannot simply supply them as arguments to the `zip()` function.

For example, given the following data structure:

```
var = [['x1' ,'x2' ,'x3'], ['y1', 'y2', 'y3'], ['z1', 'z2', 'z3'], …]
```

I would like to be able to access the following values on each iteration:

`x1,y1,z1` followed by `x2,y2,z2` followed by `x3,y3,z3` and so on.

Presumably I could achieve this using list indexes directly, or by using itertools.chain, but I'm looking for a more elegant approach using generators or otherwise.

Comment: related: [Matrix Transpose in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4937491/4279)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`zip(*var)` will automatically unpack your list of lists.

So, for example:

```
var = [['x1' ,'x2' ,'x3'], ['y1', 'y2', 'y3'], ['z1', 'z2', 'z3'], ['w1', 'w2', 'w3']]

for ltrs in zip(*var):
    print(", ".join(ltrs))
```

results in

```
x1, y1, z1, w1
x2, y2, z2, w2
x3, y3, z3, w3
```

**Edit:** per comments below, he wants to use the items from a dictionary,

```
var = {
    'id_172': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'],
    'id_182': ['y1', 'y2', 'y3'],
    'id_197': ['z1', 'z2', 'z3']
}
```

I assume we are using the values with the keys in sorted order:

```
keys = sorted(var.keys())
for ltrs in zip(*(var[k] for k in keys)):
    print(", ".join(ltrs))
```

which gives

```
x1, y1, z1
x2, y2, z2
x3, y3, z3
```

**Warning:** do note that this sorts the keys in lexocographic order (ie string alphabetical order), so for example "id_93" comes *after* "id_101". If your labels need to be sorted in numeric order you will need to use a custom key function, something like

```
keys = sorted(var.keys(), key=lambda k: int(k[3:]))
```

Comment: Wonderfully, hilariously and embarrassingly elegant. Many thanks.

Comment: Something I also mentioned in the question was the case of a dict of lists. Do you know how I can access in parallel both the keys and values (which contain lists) of a dict in this manner? Presumably I cannot use `.items()` in conjunction with `zip()`?

Comment: @bedeabc: can you give a sample dict input and output?

Comment: Many thanks @hugh. Something like `{'id_172': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], 'id_182': ['y1', 'y2', 'y3'], 'id_197': ['z1', 'z2', 'z3']}`

Comment: @bedeabc: two issues: first, a dict has no ordering; do you want the values in any particular order? second, do you want to do anything with the keys, or can they be ignored?

Comment: I solved my issue using lists of lists - I was merely curious as to whether there would be a way to access dict keys. Thanks for your comprehensive and obscenely fast answer :)

Comment: @bedeabc: if you want the keys, they are in `keys`; I have trouble seeing how you would include them as part of the data otherwise. Give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the input and output data carefully, you are actually transposing a two dimensional array. That can be done easily with Python's builtin [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function, like this

```
var = [['x1' ,'x2' ,'x3'], ['y1', 'y2', 'y3'], ['z1', 'z2', 'z3']]
print list(zip(*var))
# [('x1', 'y1', 'z1'), ('x2', 'y2', 'z2'), ('x3', 'y3', 'z3')]
```

You can iterate over it, like this

```
for x, y, z in zip(*var):
   print x, y, z
```

**Output**

```
x1 y1 z1
x2 y2 z2
x3 y3 z3
```