# python query to convert rows into columns

Tags: python

I am the input from stdin

```
macys 100
sears 20
Boscov's 5
JCPenney 21
Kohl's 22
Others 16
```

This list will grow.

I  want the output like  below

```
macys sears Boscov's JCPenney Kohl's Others 
100    20   5         21       22     16
```

Comment: Is this a list of lists, or a list of strings, or just one big string? Try [`zip(*your_list)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python)

Comment: this is input from hive query

Comment: Does that come in as a string or is it formatted a python list? If it's a single string I'd recommend parsing it into a list first before attempting any operations.

Comment: @user3426930 So in what form is the data returned? Looks like tuples to me.

Comment: select col1, col2  from hive table.  new to python. So not sure which form it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
datastring = """macys 100
sears 20
Boscov's 5
JCPenney 21
Kohl's 22
Others 16"""

converted = zip(*(line.split() for line in datastring.splitlines()))
```

`converted` is list of tuples, each containing your items in given row.

You can use `pandas` external library to easily manipulate data later:

```
import pandas as pd

dt = pd.DataFrame.from_records(converted[1:], columns=converted[0])
print dt
```

Output:

```
  macys sears Boscov's JCPenney Kohl's Others
0   100    20        5       21     22     16
```

Comment: the format is  {"Store":"Sears","count":10}
{"Store":"Sears","count":10}

Answer (score 0):

as everyone has mentioned use `cols = zip(*rows)` for example ...

```
some_text = """
macys 100
sears 20
Boscov's 5
JCPenney 21
Kohl's 22
Others 16
"""
#perhaps for you it will be some_text = sys.stdin.read()


#first convert it to a python list
some_list = some_text.splitlines()

#get rid of any empty lines
filtered_list = filter(None,some_list)

#split each line in half
rows_of_data = [line.split() for line in filtered_list]

#transpose it (turn it sideways)
headers,data = zip(*rows_of_data)


#print it out how you want
print "\n".join((" ".join(headers),
 " ".join("%-*s"%(len(headers[i]),value) for i,value in enumerate(data))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in stdin:
    a = line.split()
    list_a = a[0]
    list_b = a[1]
print list_a
print list_b
```

Comment: how can i stop the input . there is no break?