# Summing columns by specific row identifier in a 2D array

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a function that adds the values of the last 12 columns of a 2D array if the first item in each row matches another.  The first element of each row represents the department ID number so I need a cumulative total of how many hours the employees of each department worked for each month.  My 2D array is a list of lists and a sample of the data looks like this:

```
[[12606.0, 74204.0, 56.0, 64.0, 72.0, 21.6, 18.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 [12606.0, 105492.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 45.6], 
 [12606.0, 112151.0, 2.4, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 [12606.0, 121896.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 60.8, 0.0]]
```

My code is as follows:

```
   def costcentersum(A):
    """Finds the sum of the monthly hours worked by employees in each cost center.
    """
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i-1][0] == A[i][0]:
            A[i][2:] += A[i-1][2:]
    print A[i]
```

My output though is rather strange and is not the correct answer. I got this:

```
[12606.0, 121896.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 60.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 15.2, 18.4, 2.4, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 45.6, 32.0, 54.4, 52.0, 56.0, 43.2, 56.0, 64.0, 72.0, 21.6, 18.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

I want my output to not include the second column of the data (the employee ID). Just simply the dep ID and the cumulative hours for each month. Where am I going wrong in my code? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Again, you should be clear about what your data structure actually is. If you correctly format it as a list of lists (`[[12606.0, 74240.0, ...], ...]`), it makes if easier for other people to copy-paste it to test your code.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
A[i][2:] += A[i-1][2:]
```

**does not** add all of the columns individually to the row above, it *adds the lists*; `[1, 2] + [3, 4] == [1, 2, 3, 4]`. This is why your output appears so long.

Your function doesn't actually `return` anything useful, it just `print`s the last row (only the last, as the `print` is outside the `for` loop). Also, your code makes no attempt to account for cost centers not being consecutive in the file.

A much better structure would be a dictionary, where the key is the cost center ID and the values are the sums of the last twelve columns for all rows where the first column was that cost center.

```
def cost_center_sum(arr):
    out = {}
    for row in arr:
        cc = int(row[0])
        if cc not in out:
            out[cc] = [0] * 12
        out[cc] = list(map(sum, zip(out[cc], row[2:]))) # add by column
    return out
```

The highlighted line does the work of actually summing up column-by-column.

The output for your sample input:

```
{12606: [58.4, 68.0, 72.0, 21.6, 18.0, 60.8, 45.6]}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. I keep on coming across a syntax error though for the word return specifically. Did you find that as well?

Comment: @user3758443 no, works fine for me. Do you have the right number of parentheses on the line before?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**defaultdict**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) to group all rows by ID number, and a [**comprehension**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) along with [**zip(*array)**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to sum the columns (here's a [**Live Ideone Example**](https://ideone.com/U4wnnH) to play with):

**Python:**

```
A = [[12606.0, 74204.0, 56.0, 64.0, 72.0, 21.6, 18.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
     [12606.0, 105492.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 45.6], 
     [12606.0, 112151.0, 2.4, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
     [12606.0, 121896.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 60.8, 0.0],
     [12901.0, 74204.0, 25.0, 15.0, 45.0, 38.6, 18.0, 0.0, 0.0],
     [12901.0, 105492.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 45.6]]

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for row in A:                 
    d[row[0]].append(row[2:])   # append all rows with same ID number.

print {k:[sum(col) for col in zip(*rows)] for k, rows in d.items()}
```

**Output:**

```
{12606.0: [58.4, 68.0, 72.0, 21.6, 18.0, 60.8, 45.6],
 12901.0: [25.0, 15.0, 45.0, 38.6, 18.0, 0.0, 45.6]}
```

**Note:** The `zip(*rows)` is used to transpose the rows so that you can sum by column. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4937526/1290264).