# How could i print lists in python one after another

Tags: python

Assume there're three lists:

```
list1 = [a1, a2, a3]
list2 = [b1, b2, b3]
list3 = [c1, c2, c3]
```

how could I print lists one after another to get following result:

```
a1, b1, c1
a2, b2, c2
a3, b3, c3
```

Comment: related: [Matrix Transpose in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4937491/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian over-killing for this purpose, I don't want to create extra space.

Comment: @os1 If you're so much worried about space then there's [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) as well that returns iterator.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Why shouldn't I worry about space, above is a toy example with list of limited length.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary  Even zip returns iterator. yes, space is not a concern here.

Comment: @os1 Not in Python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
list2 = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
list3 = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']

for row in zip(list1, list2, list3):
    print(", ".join(row))
```

#### Output

```
a1, b1, c1
a2, b2, c2
a3, b3, c3
```

`zip()` returns an iterator in Python 3. You could use [`itertools.izip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) on Python 2 as [@Ashwini Chaudhary suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367978/how-could-i-print-lists-in-python-one-after-another#comment41393344_26367978).

Answer (score 4):

You could use `zip` to combine the lists element-wise, then `join` to create a string delimited by commas from each row.

```
list1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
list2 = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
list3 = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']

for row in zip(list1, list2, list3):
    print(', '.join(row))
```

Output

```
a1, b1, c1
a2, b2, c2
a3, b3, c3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use

```
for i in range(0,len(list1)):
   print list1[i],",",list2[i],",",list3[i]
```

Comment: if you got what you were looking for, please accept this as an answer.

Comment: I made a correction. You should is OK. But I should use zip in python since it returns a iterator.