# In Python ,how do I merge lists element wise?

Tags: python, list

I have `[[1,2,3], [5,6,7]]` and want to produce the list `[[1,5], [2,6], [3,7]]`. How do I do this in Python?

Comment: related: [Matrix Transpose in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4937491/4279)

Comment: Thank you. the matrix transpose works.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> zip([1,2,3], [4, 5, 6])
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

To convert each element to a list

```
>>> [list(a) for a in  zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])]
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Comment: This produces tuples, not lists.

Comment: anyone can easily convert them to list

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [list(x) for x in zip([1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7])]
```