# Printing nested lists in certain directions - Python

Tags: python

I am trying a problem to make Graphical designs in Python, more specifically ASCII "banner" words. Each letter is made up of a nested list of lines of the character.

```
 [[' _______ ', '(       )', '| () () |', '| || || |', '| |(_)| |', '| |   | |', '| )   ( |', '|/     \\|'], [' _______ ', '(  ____ \\', '| (    \\/', '| (__    ', '|  __)   ', '| (      ', '| (____/\\', '(_______/']]
```

etc.

When printed down for each nested list and across for the whole thing, they make a word.
I am having trouble printing it as I said above, down for each nested list and across for the whole thing.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: do you want to print each element of the lists it is unclear of what you are asking

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to print the letters from left to right, you will have to [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the list of lists with itself, effectively ["transposing"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4937491/1639625) it. This way, the first list will have all the first rows, the second list all the second rows, and so on. Now just [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) those and you are done.

```
>>> ascii = [[' _______ ', '(       )', '| () () |', '| || || |', '| |(_)| |', '| |   | |', '| )   ( |', '|/     \\|'], [' _______ ', '(  ____ \\', '| (    \\/', '| (__    ', '|  __)   ', '| (      ', '| (____/\\', '(_______/']]
>>> print '\n'.join((' '.join(line) for line in zip(*ascii))) 
 _______   _______ 
(       ) (  ____ \
| () () | | (    \/
| || || | | (__    
| |(_)| | |  __)   
| |   | | | (      
| )   ( | | (____/\
|/     \| (_______/
```

And if you want to print the letters from top to bottom, you can use this:

```
>>> print '\n\n'.join(('\n'.join(line) for line in ascii))
```

Comment: This is very nice. If `''.join(line)` is replaced by `' '.join(line)` there is a nice spacing between the two letters.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not exactly clear what output you want, I believe you could benefit from using the `string.join()` function.

**EDIT**

Aha, it's now clear what you are trying to do. Using the solution of @tobias_k I would suggest that you make it easy to edit your letters by doing something like this:

```
m = """
 _______  
(       ) 
| () () | 
| || || | 
| |(_)| | 
| |   | | 
| )   ( | 
|/     \| 
""".split('\n')

e = """
 _______  
(  ____ \ 
| (    \/ 
| (__     
|  __)    
| (       
| (____/\ 
(_______/ 
""".split('\n')

lines = zip(m,e,m,e)   # Spell the word you want here
print '\n'.join(' '.join(line) for line in lines)
```

Gives output:

```
 _______    _______    _______    _______  
(       )  (  ____ \  (       )  (  ____ \ 
| () () |  | (    \/  | () () |  | (    \/ 
| || || |  | (__      | || || |  | (__     
| |(_)| |  |  __)     | |(_)| |  |  __)    
| |   | |  | (        | |   | |  | (       
| )   ( |  | (____/\  | )   ( |  | (____/\ 
|/     \|  (_______/  |/     \|  (_______/
```