# How to re order my list of list?

Tags: python-3.x, functional-programming

I have a list like:

```
[[a,b],[c,d]]
```

and i want to have:

```
[[a,c],[b,d]]
```

using only functional programming.

Comment: Is this what you want:  `x[0][1], x[1][0] = x [1][0], x[0][1]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matrix Transpose in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Zip is your friend!

```
print(list(zip(*[[1,2],[3,4]])))
```