# Rearrange data in table

Tags: python

I have a following DataFrame:



      `dis      Country  Price
0     0.8      US        500
1     0.8      England   1000
2     0.8      Spain     1500
3     0.8      Portugal  600
4     0.8      Germany   900
5     0.9      US        2200
6     0.9      England   3000
7     0.9      Spain      600
8     0.9      Portugal  1000
9     0.9      Germany   4000`

Though I'd like to rearrange it in the following way:

`dis  US    England  Spain  Portugal   Germany

0.8  500   1000     1500   600        900
0.9  2200  3000     600    1000       4000`

I'd be happy for some ideas how to solve this problem.

Comment: are you using pandas? if so, consider adding the pandas tag

Comment: @Vivek, numpy only supports numeric values and therefor suggesting it's transpose isn't really an answer here. I like rtmh's question, are you using pandas?

Comment: Please, see this SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python
@kpie: Sorry! I just suggested a general solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `pandas`, you can use `set_index` and `unstack` to do what you are looking to do, as long as there are no repeats in the indexes:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'dis': [0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9], 'Country':['US', 'England', 'US', 'England'], 'Price':[500, 1000, 1500, 2000]})
>>> df
    Country Price   dis
0   US      500     0.8
1   England 1000    0.8
2   US      1500    0.9
3   England 2000    0.9
>>> df.set_index(['dis', 'Country']).unstack()
        Price
Country England US
dis     
0.8     1000    500
0.9     2000    1500
```

Comment: What about if I repeat indexes? I just encountered that problem.

Comment: What do you expect the output to look like when you have repeat indices?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you already know the row and column names given of your output table and that your input is a text file of tab seperated values I would do something like this,

```
afile = open("input.csv","r")
content = [k.split("\t") for k in afile.read().slit("\n")]
#If you already have a list of lists these first 2 lines are unnecessary.

output = {}
for k in content:
    if not(k[1] in output.keys):
        output[k[1]] = {}
    output[k[1]][k[2]] = k[3]

print(output)
```