# Python: Create list from comma delimited output

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a Python function that asks for the input of a cluster name that in return will pull from a csv file and returns the columns as follows:

```
server10, xxxxxxxx1, yyyyyyyy1
server11, xxxxxxxx2, yyyyyyyy2
server12, xxxxxxxx3, yyyyyyyy3
server13, xxxxxxxx4, yyyyyyyy4
server14, xxxxxxxx5, yyyyyyyy5
server15, xxxxxxxx6, yyyyyyyy6
server16, xxxxxxxx7, yyyyyyyy7
server17, xxxxxxxx8, yyyyyyyy8
server18, xxxxxxxx9, yyyyyyyy9
server19, xxxxxxx10, yyyyyyy10
```

I'm using `DictReader` class from the `csv` module. How can I put each column into a list while retaining the information of the rows?

Comment: Are you using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module from the standard library?  `csv.reader` does this automatically

Comment: Yes - tell us a little more about what you want to do with this information. using `subprocess` almost certainly isn't necessary.

Comment: You may find this solves your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to Patrick Haugh for the hint. I was able to look back at my `DictReader` function and use `hostname.append(col['hostname'])` to put the columns into separate lists.