# Python 2D list of numbers to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Im looking for the best way to convert a 2D list to csv file containing the coordinates (xyz) for every point.

The 2D-list has this format:

```
['586.732'], ['626.012'], ['496.778']
['597.422'], ['536.778'], ['586.056']
['597.422'], ['536.778'], ['586.056']
```

Using:

```
with open("output.csv", "w") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows([x, y, z])
```

will return a transposed list of objects, that cannot be plotted easily.

I would be happy if anyone could suggest a way to solve this.

Comment: Have you tried `zip()`? https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Comment: The list you have showed is not 2D. What is your desired output of the sample input?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matrix Transpose in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip()` will do what you want.

```
with open("output.csv", "w") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows( zip(x, y, z) )
```

The csv will look like

```
x1, y1, z1
x2, y2, z2
x3, y3, z3
...
```

Comment: Thank you this helps, but the result is three rows of coordinates

Comment: [['596.778'], ['596.052'],['596.778'], ['596.052'],...]