# Nested for loop to transpose matrix

Tags: python, matrix, nested

```
def transpose_matrix(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)
    vertical_to_horizontal = [[0]*n]*n
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            vertical_to_horizontal[i][j] = matrix[j][i]
    return vertical_to_horizontal


print(transpose_matrix([[1,2],[3,4]]))
```

The function is supposed to transpose a `n*n` matrix, but I get `[[2, 4], [2, 4]]` instead of the correct answer (`[1,3],[2,4]`).

I know that there are other ways to transpose a matrix, but my problem is to understand why the code above doesn't give the expected result.

Comment: Expected result?

Comment: Do you want to _transpose_ the matrix?

Comment: @PatrickArtner[ [1,3],[2,4]]  :}

Comment: @ForceBru Yes! I did not see the logic error in my function but it does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matrix Transpose in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python)

Comment: @NilsWerner Thanks for the helping. I find the right way to transpose the matrix. Could you tell me why my codes does not work? Thank you so much!

Comment: voting to leave open as not a duplicate nor off-topic, as question clearly asks for explanation of mistake (not present in linked duplicate), and shows MCVE, + wrong obtained result vs expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is correct, the problem lies in the way you create your empty matrix at the beginning, with

```
vertical_to_horizontal = [[0]*n]*n
```

The inner `[0]*n` creates a list `[0, 0]`

Then, the outer `*` operator creates a list that references twice this inner list - the very same object.

```
n = 2
v_to_h = [[0]*n] * n
print(id(v_to_h[0]), id(v_to_h[1]))
#140243497120456 140243497120456
```

The two [0, 0] lists in your matrix are in fact the same object, as their identical ids shows. So, when we do

```
v_to_h[0][0] = 5
```

we update the 0th element of v_to_h[0], but v_to_h[0] and v_to_h[1] are the same object, so we get twice the same list in the matrix:

```
print(v_to_h)
#[[5, 0], [5, 0]]
```

If you want to prevent that, you have to create different inner lists, so don't use the `*` operator.

You can use a list comprehension, as in:

```
n = 2
v_to_h = [[0]*n for i in range(n)]
print(id(v_to_h[0]), id(v_to_h[1]))
#140243437130184 140243512804488
```

Here, our two lists are different objects.

So, your code could be:

```
def transpose_matrix(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)
    vertical_to_horizontal = [[0]*n for i in range(n)]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            vertical_to_horizontal[i][j] = matrix[j][i]
    return vertical_to_horizontal


print(transpose_matrix([[1,2],[3,4]]))
#[[1, 3], [2, 4]]
```

which does what you expect - though there are, of course, shorter and more efficient ways to transpose a matrix, as already indicated in the comments.

Comment: Nice demonstration!

Comment: indeed. Just so you can spot this kind of issue, here is a "debugging" version : https://repl.it/repls/JointKlutzyVixen . You can clearly see that both "lines" are being modified at the same time, showing they refer to the same internal array.

Answer (score -1):

```
def transpose_matrix(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)
    vertical_to_horizontal = []
    for i in range(n):
        vertical_to_horizontal.append([i]*n)
        for j in range(n):
            vertical_to_horizontal[i][j] = matrix[j][i]
    return vertical_to_horizontal


print(transpose_matrix([[1,2],[3,4]]))
```