# transpose row by row in excel using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, openpyxl, xlrd

Is there any solution in python to transpose EXCEL multiple rows into one column and store it in the new Excel file,without DataFrame?

```
 COL1    COL2   COL3
  A       B      C
  D       E      F
  G       H      I
```

TRANSPOSE

```
COL1  A
COL1  D
COL1  G
COL2  B
COL2  E
COL2  H
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you made a two dimensional array of the data? Something like:

```
exceldata =  [[col1,col2,col3],[A,B,C],[D,E,F],[G,H,I]]
transposed_data = zip(*theArray)
```

Then loop through every array in the 2d array and input that into the excel sheet as a row

See also: [Matrix Transpose in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python)

Comment: For obtaining the excel data into a 2d array: loop through each column while the cell value != '' and do the same for each row to obtain how many rows and columns the excel sheet has.