# How to pass list of tuple to lamda function

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, lambda

When list of tuples are used in for loop it works perfectly with two separate variables as below

```
t_dict = {
    "k1": "v1",
    "k2": "v2",
    "k3": "v3",
    "k4": "v4",
    "k5": "v5"
}

for k, v in t_dict.items():
    print "%s=%s" % (k, v)
```

But when converted into lambda with map function got an error as below

```
print map(lambda k, v: "%s=%s" % (k, v), t_dict.items())

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    print map(lambda k, v: "%s=%s" % (k, v), t_dict.items()) TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Is there any other way to call list of tuple in lambda function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Built-in `map` supports multiple iterables:

```
res = map(lambda k, v: "%s=%s" % (k, v), t_dict, t_dict.values())
# ['k1=v1', 'k2=v2', 'k3=v3', 'k4=v4', 'k5=v5']
```

As described in the docs for [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

> If additional *iterable* arguments are passed, *function* must take
>   that many arguments and is applied to the items from all iterables in
>   parallel.

Comment: there should be a more elegant way, `map('{}={}'.format, t_dict, t_dict.values())` is the best I could think of

Comment: @Chris_Rands, Yup, good point. However, I wanted to advise OP on the more general issue of how to use a multi-argument function with `map`.

Answer (score 1):

For you case, you can also use the tuple after the `%` for formatting, so:

```
map(lambda t: "%s=%s" % t, t_dict.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested, you can pass multiple iterables to `map`, but if you want to pass the `items` and not `keys` and `values` individually, you can use `zip(*...)` to ["transpose"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4937526/1639625) the items to two lists and use `*` again to pass those as two different arguments to `map`:

```
>>> list(map(lambda k, v: "%s=%s" % (k, v), *zip(*t_dict.items())))
['k1=v1', 'k2=v2', 'k3=v3', 'k4=v4', 'k5=v5']
```

Or use [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> list(starmap(lambda k, v: "%s=%s" % (k, v), t_dict.items()))
['k1=v1', 'k2=v2', 'k3=v3', 'k4=v4', 'k5=v5']
```

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yes, that's nicer that the `lambda`, but it's still a function taking two paramters, thus this does not really change anything about the core issue.

Answer (score 0):

Other option is this way ([`str.join(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)) to get the list of strings:

```
map( lambda t: "=".join(t), t_dict.items() )
#=> ['k3=v3', 'k2=v2', 'k1=v1', 'k5=v5', 'k4=v4']
```

This version can also print out:

```
import sys
map( lambda t: sys.stdout.write("=".join(t) + "\n"), t_dict.items() )

# k3=v3
# k2=v2
# k1=v1
# k5=v5
# k4=v4
```