# Creating one nested list from separate lists

Tags: python, list

Say I have the following lists:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_3 = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue']
```

And I want to create one list of lists, as follows:

```
combined_list = [[1, 'a', 'red'],
                 [2, 'b', 'yellow'],
                 [3, 'c', 'blue']]
```

What is the best way of going about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matrix Transpose in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python)

Comment: It's not an **exact** duplicate but it's incredibly close, and the core of the solution (`zip()`) is what matters.

Answer (score 2):

Just use zip.
You will need to cast each produced tuple into a list and use a list comprehension as the following example:

```
combined_list = [list(tuple) for tuple in zip(list_1, list_2, list_3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3] 
list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
list_3 = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue']

combined_list = []
combined_list+=map(list, zip(list_1, list_2, list_3))
print(combined_list)
```

Result:

```
[[1, 'a', 'red'], [2, 'b', 'yellow'], [3, 'c', 'blue']]
```

Comment: This is just going to create a list of lists, without mixing elements in the way OP is asking for.

Comment: @Minyc510 , yes, you are right. I wrongly read the task first. But already corrected the answer

Answer (score 0):

#### ASSUMPTIONS:

All your lists `list_1`,`list_2` and `list_3` are of equal length

#### Solution

You simply iterate through the list and append the combined list for each index to an an empty list

```py
def combine(l1,l2,l3):
    res = []
    for i in range(len(l1)):
        res.append([l1[i],l2[i],l3[i]])
    return res
```

Now you can simply call this function with your lists `list_1`, `list_2` and `list_3` like this

```py
combined = combine(list_1,list_2,list_3)
```