# How to transpose a 2D array using numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to convert this array

```python
[array([46, 64, 50, 66]),
 array([53, 61, 59, 59]),
 array([54, 63, 55, 61]),
 array([56, 58, 51, 55])]
```

into this array

```python
[array([46, 53, 54, 56]),
 array([64, 61, 63, 58]),
 array([50, 59, 55, 51]),
 array([66, 59, 61, 55])]
```

Is there a way to do this in numpy?

Comment: Explain what exactly you want to do, instead of providing just an example.

Comment: Although you're looking for the transposition operator.

Comment: @user202729, Exactly. I want to rearrange this array.

Comment: Mostly duplicate of [python - How to flip numpy array along the diagonal efficiently? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61198658/how-to-flip-numpy-array-along-the-diagonal-efficiently) , although the answers there are terrible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Numpy allows you to transpose. Cast the list to numpy array and use `.T`

```
import numpy as np

case = [np.array([46, 64, 50, 66]),
 np.array([53, 61, 59, 59]),
 np.array([54, 63, 55, 61]),
 np.array([56, 58, 51, 55])]

# transform `[ ]` list to array and then `.T`
np.array(case).T # Transpose
```

See documentation of [Transpose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

check out this python docs link for help
Check for transpose function in numpy as follows
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html

Comment: @user202729 Thanks. This was really helpful.

Comment: kindly mark this answer as accepted if it helped