# Numpy rotate and save 2D array to a CSV

Tags: python, numpy

How can I save a 2D array into a CSV by rotating the array by 90 degree?

I tried numpy np.rot90, it alters the position of the elements.

```
>>> a = np.array([[88,87],[78,77],[68,67],[58,57]])
>>> a
array([[88, 87],
       [78, 77],
       [68, 67],
       [58, 57]])
>>>
```

csv should look like -

```
88, 78, 68, 58
87, 77, 67, 57
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transpose a 2D array using numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66546492/how-to-transpose-a-2d-array-using-numpy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
a = np.array([[88, 87], [78, 77], [68, 67], [58, 57]])

np.savetxt("data.csv", a.T, delimiter=",", fmt="%i")
```

Saves `data.csv`:

```
88,78,68,58
87,77,67,57
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [transpose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) the array.

```py
>>> a = np.array([[88,87],[78,77],[68,67],[58,57]])
>>> a
array([[88, 87],
       [78, 77],
       [68, 67],
       [58, 57]])
>>> a.T
array([[88, 78, 68, 58],
       [87, 77, 67, 57]])
>>> a = a.T
>>> np.savetxt('a.csv', a, delimiter=", ", fmt="%i")
```