# Python zip inner list of a random list

Tags: python

My code:

```
import random
randomlist = []
result_list=[]
l=int(input('Enter List Length'))
for i in range(0,l):
    n = random.randint(1,30)
    randomlist.append(n)
print(randomlist)
n=int(input('composite range:'))
composite_list = [randomlist[x:x + n] for x in range(0, len(randomlist), n)]
print(composite_list)
# zip inner list
for i in composite_list:
    #stucked here
```

I wish to zip all list elements to a new list for example:

Random List: `[25, 6, 15, 7, 21, 30, 10, 14, 3]`

composite_list:`[[25, 6, 15], [7, 21, 30], [10, 14, 3]]`

Output list after zip: `[[25, 7, 10],[6, 21, 14],[15, 30, 3]]`

Because number of elements in `composite_list` is randomly. I have no idea how to use `zip()`

Comment: `list(zip(*composite_list))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matrix Transpose in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
rand_lst = [25, 6, 15, 7, 21, 30, 10, 14, 3]

it = iter(rand_lst)
comp_lst = list(zip(it, it, it))
# [(25, 6, 15), (7, 21, 30), (10, 14, 3)]

trans_lst = list(zip(*comp_lst))
# [(25, 7, 10), (6, 21, 14), (15, 30, 3)]
```

This uses the old "`zip` iterator with itself" pattern to create the chunks. Then you can zip the chunks by unpacking the list using the `*` operator. This also works in a single step:

```
it = iter(rand_lst)
trans_lst = list(zip(*zip(it, it, it)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
list(zip(*composite_list))
# output is a list of tuples
```

Or:

```
list(map(list, zip(*composite_list)))
# output is a list of lists
```

to look exactly your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

np.array(composite_list).T.tolist()
```

Outputs:

```py
[[25, 7, 10], [6, 21, 14], [15, 30, 3]]
```

*Caveat* would be probably even better, if you would keep your whole flow in `numpy`, otherwise converting to `numpy` might be a bit of a overhead.