# how to separate different elements in a list in python and put them in a new list

Tags: python

I want to separate different numbers in this list:

```
[([2437], [0.235]), ([4942], [0.217])]
```

and put them in new lists. Python returns length of this list equal to 2. I need to have two lists like these: `[2437, 4942]` and `[0.235, 0.217]`.

How can I able to reach these lists from the above list in python?

Comment: What have you tried to accomplish that and what technical issue have faced?

Comment: Your example looks like a matrix transpose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python. But your example is too simple. Will there always be 2 elements in a tuple? Are all tuple elements just a list of a single element?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matrix Transpose in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method for Python 3:

```
>>> my_list = [([2437], [0.235]), ([4942], [0.217])]
>>> sub_list1, sub_list2 = [[*item1, *item2] for item1, item2 in zip(*my_list)]
>>> sub_list1
[2437, 4942]
>>> sub_list2
[0.235, 0.217]
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's always two tuples of two single item lists, another way to unpack:

```
l1, l2 = [[inner_list[i][0] for inner_list in my_list] for i in range(2)]
```