# Swtich rows and column in a chart

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have a table that can have any number of rows but fixed number of columns.

I'm able to chart the graph by column but now I want to chart them up by switching rows and column. From the Sheet I can do it with a single click "Swtich rows or column" in chart selection.
How should I implement the same using Sheets APIv4? I'm using python sdk, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

### Unfortunately this is not possible via Sheets API or [Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference)

As a workaround you can create the graph with the data from a dummy sheet which you populate with transposed data - either programmaticaly or by cell formula.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python) post for transposing in Python.

Comment: Had to program a function to  create series for rows and fixed number of column for my use-case.