# transpose of non-square matrix

Tags: python, matrix

To transpose the matrix, my code is like this:

def transpose(matrix):

```
temp_Matrix = matrix[:][:]

for i in range(len(matrix)):

    for j in range(len(matrix[0]):

        temp_Matrix[i][j]=matrix[j][i]

return temp_Matrix
```

why this code does not work for the non-square matrix?

Comment: `matrix[:][:]` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: you could just pass your 2D array to numpy and use numpy for matrix transpose. so much easier than re-writing matrix transpose yourself :)

Comment: yeah but the assignment says do not use numpy

Answer (score 0):

I can't make a comment yet, but here is a post asking about a transpose of a matrix with so many different variations. Take a look:

[Transpose in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python)