# writing data columns in CSV file

Tags: python, csv

Basically, I want to write the data I have onto a .csv file in a specific layout. I have three arrays (one with x-coordinates, one with y-coordinates and one with z-coordinates) and I want them to be in three columns on the csv file.

For example, my arrays are:

```
x_array = [1,2,3,4,5]
y_array = [6,7,8,9,0]
z_array = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and on the csv file they should look like this:

```
1,6,1
2,7,2
3,8,3
4,9,4
5,0,5
```

So far I have tried to use panda dataframe, but I cannot quite unpack this the way I need to later on, so I need a different method. I am out of ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matrix Transpose in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python)

Comment: Just rotate the array before you convert it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just rotate the array before you convert it into csv

Here is an example of what you could do :

```py
>>> x_array = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> y_array = [6,7,8,9,0]
>>> z_array = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> xyz_array = [x_array, y_array, z_array]
>>> xyz_array = list(zip(*xyz_array[::-1]))
>>> for x in xyz_array:
...     for y in x:
...             print(f'{y},', end='')
...     print()
... 
1,6,1,
2,7,2,
3,8,3,
4,9,4,
5,0,5,
```