# Returning matrix columns as lists in Python

Tags: python, matrix

If I have the following matrix:

```
m = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6], 
     [7, 8, 9]]
```

how do I return a list that looks like this

```
[[1, 4, 7], 
 [2, 5, 8], 
 [3, 6, 9]]
```

without using built-in functions?

Edit: I can use len() and range()

Comment: `list(zip(*m))`?

Comment: @DaniMesejo Without built.ins?

Comment: So cannot use range? For example? or len?

Comment: no `zip`, no `range`, no `len`, no `enumerate` :D

Comment: Yes, I can use range, sorry haha, I meant if there are any other built-ins that are specifically made for this type of problem

Comment: What you want to achieve is called (matrix) *transposition*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matrix Transpose in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested comprehension, à la:

```
[[row[i] for row in m] for i in range(len(m[0]))]
```

If the typical transpositioning idiom `zip(*m)` (or `[*map(list, zip(*m))]` if exact types matter) is to be avoided as too purpose-built.

Comment: other version [[m[j][i] for j, _ in enumerate(m[i])] for i,_ in enumerate(m)] with minimal builtins

Comment: True, however, I would consider `enumerate` a "higher level" util than `range` and `len` :)

Answer (score 1):

Weird approach:

```
m = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]

res = map(lambda *args: args, *m)
print(list(res))
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

If list are required:

```
res = list(map(lambda *args: list(args), *m))
print(res)
```

Alternative:

```
res = [*map(lambda *args: list(args), *m)]
```

Comment: Very creative `zip` implementation: `zip = lambda *iterables: map(lambda *args: args, *iterables)` One does have to stare down what's happening though :D +1

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
m = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6], 
     [7, 8, 9]]
result=[[0 for i in range(len(m))] for j in range(len(m[0]))]
for i in range(len(m)):
    for j in range(len(m[0])):
        result[j][i]=m[i][j]
print(result)
```