# transpose matrices(as tuples) in python without numpy

Tags: python, matrix

I have to write a function transpose() that transposes both square matrices(n rows x n columns) and rectangular (mxn) matrices using tuples

```
def transpose(matrix):
    rows = len(matrix)
    columns = len(matrix[0])
    matrix_T = []
    for j in range(columns):
        row = []
        for i in range(rows):
           row.append(matrix[i][j])
        matrix_T.append(row)
    return matrix_T
```

this is the code i found for transposing matrices, however, it does not work for my task, as the expected result is tuple and the actual result is, i assume, list
i'd be really thankful if there's someone who could help me adapt the code to fit my needs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hX2vz.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matrix Transpose in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python)

Comment: Do you know how to convert a list into a tuple?

Comment: I've already looked through the answers, they are mostly using lists and arrays, and it might be right, but I'm looking for tuples

Comment: TLDR: ``def transpose(matrix): return tuple(zip(*matrix))``

Comment: thank you :) it works ♥